# How to initialize log4j properly?

Tags: log4j

After adding log4j to my application I get the following output every time I execute my application:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (slideselector.facedata.FaceDataParser).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

It seems this means a configuration file is missing.
Where should this config file be located and what is a good start content?

I'm using plain java for developing a desktop application. So no webserver etc...

Comment: for all maven guys like me: put the log4j.properties into src/main/resources !!

Comment: The log4j documentation has a very [basic sample of a log4j.xml file](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat).

Comment: It is very helpful to go over the short manual of Log4j: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 305, accepted):

`Log4j` by default looks for a file called `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` on the classpath.

You can control which file it uses to initialize itself by setting system properties as described [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) (Look for the "Default Initialization Procedure" section).

For example:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=customName ....
```

Will cause `log4j` to look for a file called customName on the classpath.

If you are having problems I find it helpful to turn on the log4j.debug:

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

It will print to System.out lots of helpful information about which file it used to initialize itself, which loggers / appenders got configured and how etc.

The configuration file can be a java properties file or an xml file. Here is a sample of the properties file format taken from [the log4j intro documentation page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html):

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Comment: So for loading the configuartion file from  a file which is not on a classpath you have to do it like: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/c:/my/folder/log4j.properties which is actually a URL.

Comment: one small tip that maybe someone will find useful: you can also turn on the _log4j_ debugger by enabling the corresponding property in code - **System.setProperty("log4j.debug", "");**

Comment: Where do you put `java -Dlog4j.configuration=customName`? I tried Project / Preferences / Run/Debug Settings , picked some configurations, clicked Edit, Arguments tab, VM arguments. Does the customName include a .xml extension?

Comment: After trying many variations, this worked: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///C:/mydir/subdir/log4j.properties   The example above: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/c:/my/folder/log4j.properties failed.

Comment: I really wish manuals would emphasize more that `-Dlog4j.debug` can help debug your configuration.

Comment: Note that this property name has changed in log4j2. Use `-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=myConfig` instead

Answer (score 257):

While setting up log4j properly is great for "real" projects you might want a quick-and-dirty solution, e.g. if you're just testing a new library.

If so a call to the static method

```
org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

will setup basic logging to the console, and the error messages will be gone.

Comment: Hi a3. 14_Infinity where i should use this? i can't understand. even i have referred more answers for this issue. please help me

Comment: Keep in mind that this will default to Debug-level logging, which may not be desirable. You can change this like so: `Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.INFO);`

Comment: Not just did the warnings go away, but I got some handy debug info output in the console window

Comment: so ironic..we use it on the production state

Answer (score 26):

If you just get rid of everything (e.g. if you are in tests)

```
org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure(new NullAppender());
```

Answer (score 22):

As per [Apache Log4j FAQ page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html):

> Why do I see a warning about "No appenders found for logger" and "Please configure log4j properly"?
>
> This occurs when the default configuration **files `log4j.properties` and `log4j.xml` can not be found** and the application performs no explicit configuration. `log4j` uses `Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource()` to locate the default configuration files and does not directly check the file system. Knowing the appropriate location to place log4j.properties or `log4j.xml` requires understanding the search strategy of the class loader in use. `log4j` does not provide a default configuration since output to the console or to the file system may be prohibited in some environments.

Basically the warning *No appenders could be found for logger* means that you're using [`log4j`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) logging system, but you haven't added any Appenders (such as FileAppender, ConsoleAppender, SocketAppender, SyslogAppender, etc.) into your configuration file or the configuration file is missing.

There are three ways to configure log4j: with a properties file (`log4j.properties`), with an [XML file](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) and through Java code (`rootLogger.addAppender(new NullAppender());`).

#### `log4j.properties`

If you've property file present (e.g. when installing Solr), you need to place this file within your [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) directory.

#### classpath

Here are some command suggestions in Linux how to determine your classpath value:

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
$ ps wuax | grep -i classpath
$ grep -Ri classpath /etc/tomcat? /var/lib/tomcat?/conf /usr/share/tomcat?
```

or from Java: `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`.

#### Log4j XML

Below is a basic XML configuration file for log4j in XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>
  
</log4j:configuration>
```

#### Tomcat

If you're using Tomcat, you may place your `log4j.properties` into:  `/usr/share/tomcat?/lib/` or `/var/lib/tomcat?/webapps/*/WEB-INF/lib/` folder.

#### Solr

For the reference, Solr default `log4j.properties` file looks like:

```
#  Logging level
solr.log=logs/
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x \u2013 %m%n

#- size rotation with log cleanup.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=4MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=9

#- File to log to and log format
log4j.appender.file.File=${solr.log}/solr.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}; %C; %m\n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=WARN

# set to INFO to enable infostream log messages
log4j.logger.org.apache.solr.update.LoggingInfoStream=OFF
```

---

Why can't log4j find my properties file in a J2EE or WAR application?

> The short answer: the log4j classes and the properties file are not within the scope of the same classloader.
>
> Log4j only uses the default `Class.forName()` mechanism for loading classes. Resources are handled similarly. See the documentation for `java.lang.ClassLoader` for more details.
>
> So, if you're having problems, try loading the class or resource yourself. If you can't find it, neither will log4j. ;)

---

See also:

- [Short introduction to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) at Apache site
- [Apache: Logging Services: FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig) at Apache site

Answer (score 13):

Find a log4j.properties or log4j.xml online that has a root appender, and put it on your classpath.

```
### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
```

will log to the console. I prefer logging to a file so you can investigate afterwards.

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.File=test.log
log4j.appender.file.threshold=debug
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=debug,file
```

although for verbose logging applications 100KB usually needs to be increased to 1MB or 10MB, especially for debug.

Personally I set up multiple loggers, and set the root logger to warn or error level instead of debug.

Answer (score 13):

You can set the location of your log4j.properties from inside your java app by using:

```
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(file/location/log4j.properties)
```

More information is available here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: Hmmm, class not found. An `import` statement is always helpful as code completion is not all that reliable.

Answer (score 10):

Another way to do it without putting the property file on the classpath, is to set the property from the java code directly. Here is the sample code.

```
public class Log4JSample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties properties=new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("log4j.rootLogger","TRACE,stdout,MyFile");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.rootCategory","TRACE");

    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.stdout",     "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.stdout.layout",  "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern","%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%5p] %t (%F) - %m%n");

    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.MyFile", "org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.MyFile.File", "my_example.log");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.MyFile.MaxFileSize", "100KB");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.MyFile.MaxBackupIndex", "1");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.MyFile.layout",  "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout");
    properties.setProperty("log4j.appender.MyFile.layout.ConversionPattern","%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%5p] %t (%F) - %m%n");

    PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyFile");

    logger.fatal("This is a FATAL message.");
    logger.error("This is an ERROR message.");
    logger.warn("This is a WARN message.");
    logger.info("This is an INFO message.");
    logger.debug("This is a DEBUG message.");
    logger.trace("This is a TRACE message.");
}
```

}

Answer (score 7):

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
```

> Call this method

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Comment: Specifically, this writes to `System.out`. The javadoc for the no-args configure method says:
`Add a ConsoleAppender that uses PatternLayout using the  PatternLayout#TTCC_CONVERSION_PATTERN and
     prints to System.out to the root category.`

Answer (score 6):

You can set up the log level by using [setLevel()](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#setLevel%28org.apache.log4j.Level%29).

The levels are useful to easily set the kind of informations you want the program to display.

For example:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN); //will not show debug messages
```

The set of possible levels are:

> TRACE,
>
> DEBUG,
>
> INFO,
>
> WARN,
>
> ERROR and
>
> FATAL

According to [Logging Services manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

Answer (score 3):

To enable `-Dlog4j.debug`, I go to *System, Advanced system settings, Environment variables* and set system variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to `-Dlog4j.debug`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, create log4j.properties under src/main/assembly folder. Depending on if you want log messages to be shown in the console or in the file you modify your file. The following is going to show your messages in the console.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you developing in? Are you using Apache Tomcat?

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [[%5p] %c{1} [%t]] %m%n
```

I have a properties like this in a Java app of mine.

Answer (score 2):

I've created file **log4j.properties** in *resources* folder next to **hibernate.cfg.xml** file and filled it with text below:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] %m%n
```

now I got rid of warnings and errors

Answer (score 1):

My log4j got fixed by below property file:

```
## direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/test.log
log4j.appender.file.threshold=debug
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=debug,file
```

Comment: Hi, how can I add config it for debug to console and error to file?

Answer (score 1):

As explained earlier there are 2 approaches

First one is to just add this line to your main method:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Second approach is to add this standard log4j.properties file to your classpath:

While taking second approach you need to make sure you initialize the file properly.

Eg.

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.load(new FileInputStream("log4j property file path"));

props.setProperty("log4j.appender.File.File", "Folder where you want to store log files/" + "File Name");
```

Make sure you create required folder to store log files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set debug attribut in log4j:configuration node to true.

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
```

It prints out information as the configuration file is read and used to configure the log4j environment. You may be got more details to resolve your problem.

Comment: Does anyone know? Is the same option also usable from properties configuration without falling back to setting -Dlog4j.debug=true at runtime startup?

Answer (score 1):

[**Logging API**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/index.html) - *The Java Logging API facilitates software servicing and maintenance at customer sites by producing log reports suitable for analysis by end users, system administrators, field service engineers, and software development teams. The Logging APIs capture information such as security failures, configuration errors, performance bottlenecks, and/or bugs in the application or platform. The core package includes support for delivering plain text or XML formatted log records to memory, output streams, consoles, files, and sockets. In addition, the logging APIs are capable of interacting with logging services that already exist on the host operating system.*

Package <sup>[java.util.logging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)</sup> « Provides the classes and interfaces of the Java platform's core logging facilities.

---

[***Log4j 1.x***](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Abstract) « log4j is a popular Java-based logging utility. Log4j is an open source project based on the work of many authors. It allows the developer to control which log statements are output to a variety of locations by using Appenders [console, files, DB and email]. It is fully configurable at runtime using external configuration files.

> Log4j has three main components:
>
> - [Loggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j#Log4j_log_levels)   - [OFF, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE]
> - Appenders
>
>   > - **Apache Commons Logging:** ConsoleAppender, FileAppender, RollingFileAppender, DailyRollingFileAppender, JDBCAppender-[`Driver`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.34), [SocketAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11759549/5081877)
>   > - **Log4J Appender for MongoDB:** [MongoDbAppender](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.log4mongo/log4mongo-java/0.9.0) - [`Driver`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.6.0)
> - Layouts   - [PatternLayout, EnhancedPatternLayout]

---

Configuration files can be written in XML or in Java properties (key=value) format.

> 1. log4j_External.properties « Java properties (key=value) format
>
> *The string between an opening "**${**" and closing "**}**" is interpreted as a key. The value of the substituted variable can be defined as a system property or in the configuration file itself.
>   Set appender specific options. « log4j.appender.appenderName.option=value, For each named appender you can configure its Layout.*

```properties
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE, FILE_PER_SIZE, FILE_PER_DAY, CONSOLE, MySql

#log.path=./
log.path=E:/Logs

# https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
# {%-5p - [WARN ,INFO ,ERROR], %5p 0- [ WARN, INFO,ERROR]}
log.patternLayout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log.pattern=%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %C{1}:%12.20M:%L - %m %n

# System.out | System.err
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.err
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=${log.patternLayout}
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=${log.pattern}

# File Appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log.path}/logFile.log
#log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed. - Defaults setFile(null,true)
#log4j.appender.FILE.Append = false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=${log.patternLayout}
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=${log.pattern}

# BackUP files for every Day.
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_DAY=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
# [[ Current File ] - logRollingDayFile.log ], { [BackUPs] logRollingDayFile.log_2017-12-10, ... }
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_DAY.File=${log.path}/logRollingDayFile.log
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_DAY.DatePattern='_'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_DAY.layout=${log.patternLayout}
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_DAY.layout.ConversionPattern=${log.pattern}

# BackUP files for size rotation with log cleanup.
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_SIZE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# [[ Current File ] - logRollingFile.log ], { [BackUPs] logRollingFile.log.1, logRollingFile.log.2}
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_SIZE.File=${log.path}/logRollingFile.log
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_SIZE.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_SIZE.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_SIZE.layout=${log.patternLayout}
log4j.appender.FILE_PER_SIZE.layout.ConversionPattern=${log.pattern}

# MySql Database - JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.MySql=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.MySql.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.MySql.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/automationlab
log4j.appender.MySql.user=root
log4j.appender.MySql.password=
log4j.appender.MySql.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.MySql.layout.ConversionPattern=INSERT INTO `logdata` VALUES ('%p', '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', '%C', '%M', '%L', '%m');
#log4j.appender.MySql.sql=INSERT INTO `logdata` VALUES ('%p', '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', '%C', '%M', '%L', '%m');

# Direct log events[Messages] to MongoDB Collection - MongoDbAppender
log.mongoDB.hostname=loalhost
log.mongoDB.userName=Yash777
log.mongoDB.password=Yash@123
log.mongoDB.DB=MyLogDB
log.mongoDB.Collection=Logs

log4j.appender.MongoDB=org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender
log4j.appender.MongoDB.hostname=${log.mongoDB.hostname}
log4j.appender.MongoDB.userName=${log.mongoDB.userName}
log4j.appender.MongoDB.password=${log.mongoDB.password}
log4j.appender.MongoDB.port=27017
log4j.appender.MongoDB.databaseName=${log.mongoDB.DB}
log4j.appender.MongoDB.collectionName=${log.mongoDB.Collection}
log4j.appender.MongoDB.writeConcern=FSYNCED
```

MySQL Table structure for table `logdata`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logdata` (
  `Logger_Level` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `DataTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ClassName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MethodName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `LineNumber` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Message` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

> 2. log4j_External.xml « XML [log4j:configuration with public DTD file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852980/5081877)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC
  "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false">

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="target" value="System.out" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %C{1}:%12.20M:%L - %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="E:/Logs/logFile.log" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %C{1}:%12.20M:%L - %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_PER_SIZE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="E:/Logs/logRollingFile.log" />
        <param name="immediateFlush" value="true"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="100KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %C{1}:%12.20M:%L - %m %n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE_PER_DAY" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="E:/Logs/logRollingDayFile.log" />
        <param name="datePattern" value="'_'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %C{1}:%12.20M:%L - %m %n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_PER_SIZE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_PER_DAY" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

---

> 3. Log4j Configuration from the URL in Java program:
>
> In order to specify a custom configuration with an external file, the used class must implement the [*Configurator interface*](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Configurator.html).
>
> when default configuration files "log4j.properties", "log4j.xml" are not available
>
> - For "log4j.properties" you can fed to the [*PropertyConfigurator*](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).configure(java.net.URL) method.
> - For "log4j.xml" [*DOMConfigurator*](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html) will be used.

```java
public class LogFiles {
    // Define a static logger variable so that it references the Logger instance named "LogFiles".
    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger( LogFiles.class );

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("CONFIGURATION_FILE « "+LogManager.DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE);
        System.out.println("DEFAULT_XML_CONFIGURATION_FILE = 'log4j.xml' « Default access modifier");

        String fileName = //"";
                //"log4j_External.xml";
                "log4j_External.properties";
        String configurationFile = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/" + fileName;

        if( fileName.contains(".xml") ) {
            DOMConfigurator.configure( configurationFile );
            log.info("Extension *.xml");
        } else if ( fileName.contains(".properties") ) {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure( configurationFile );
            log.info("Extension *.properties");
        } else {
            DailyRollingFileAppender dailyRollingAppender = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
            dailyRollingAppender.setFile("E:/Logs/logRollingDayFile.log");
            dailyRollingAppender.setDatePattern("'_'yyyy-MM-dd");

            PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();
            layout.setConversionPattern( "%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %C{1}:%12.20M:%L - %m %n" );
            dailyRollingAppender.setLayout(layout);

            dailyRollingAppender.activateOptions();

            Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
            rootLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
            rootLogger.addAppender(dailyRollingAppender);

            log.info("Configuring from Java Class.");
        }

        log.info("Console.Message.");
        method2();
        methodException(0);
    }

    static void method2() {
        log.info("method2 - Console.Message.");
    }
    static void methodException(int b) {
        try {
            int a = 10/b;
            System.out.println("Result : "+ a);
            log.info("Result : "+ a);
        } catch (Exception ex) { // ArithmeticException: / by zero
            log.error(String.format("\n\tException occurred: %s", stackTraceToString(ex)));
        }
    }
    public static String stackTraceToString(Exception ex) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For testing, a quick-dirty way including setting log level:

```
org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.WARN);

// set to Level.DEBUG for full, or Level.OFF..
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to put "log4j.properties" into the "src" folder.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using apache commons logging wrapper on top of log4j, then we need to have both the jars available in classpath. Also, `commons-logging.properties` and `log4j.properties/xml` should be available in classpath.

We can also pass implementation class and `log4j.properties` name as `JAVA_OPTS` either using `-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=<logging implementation class name> -Dlog4j.configuration=<file:location of log4j.properties/xml file>`. Same can be done via setting `JAVA_OPTS` in case of app/web server.

It will help to externalize properties which can be changed in deployment.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way using .yaml

Logic Structure:

```
Configuration:
    Properties:
    Appenders:
    Loggers:
```

Sample:

```
Configutation:
    name: Default

    Properties:
        Property:
            name: log-path
            value: "logs"

    Appenders:

        Console:
        name: Console_Appender
        target: SYSTEM_OUT
        PatternLayout:
            pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

       File:
          name: File_Appender
          fileName: ${log-path}/logfile.log
          PatternLayout:
            pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    Loggers:

        Root:
            level: debug
            AppenderRef:
              - ref: Console_Appender

        Logger:
            - name: <package>.<subpackage>.<subsubpackage>.<...>
              level: debug
              AppenderRef:
                 - ref: File_Appender
                 level: error
```

Ref: [LOG4J 2 CONFIGURATION: USING YAML](https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-yaml/)

Answer (score 0):

Maven solution:

I came across all the same issues as above, and for a maven solution I used 2 dependencies. This configuration is only meant for quick testing if you want a simple project to be using a logger, with a standard configuration. I can imagine you want to make a configuration file later on if you need more information and or finetune your own logging levels.

```
    <properties>
        <slf4jVersion>1.7.28</slf4jVersion>
    </properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and the issue was fixed.

Followed the below blog

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206875685-How-to-fix-log4j-WARN-console-messages-when-running-an-Application-inside-IntelliJ-Idea

But here he says like below

*To fix that just enter the following log4j.resources file into main/resources folder of your project*

instead of creating log4j.resources, create log4j.properties. Right Click on Resource in IntelliJ -> New -> Resource Bundle - Just name it as log4j

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this error on Intellij IDEA even after adding the `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file on your resources test folder, maybe the Intellij IDEA is not aware yet about the existence of the file.

So, after add the file, right click on the file and choose **Recompile log4j.xml**.