# Where should I put the log4j.properties file?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, log4j

I wrote a web service project using netbeans 6.7.1 with glassfish v2.1, put log4j.properties to the root dir of project and use:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

in Constructor:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

and in functions:

```
logger.info("...");
logger.error("...");
// ...
```

but, it is error info(actually, I have tried to put it almost every dir that I could realize):

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:297)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:315)
        at com.corp.ors.demo.OrsDemo.main(OrisDemo.java:228)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [log4j.properties].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.corp.ors.demo.OrsDemo).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

the example project could be get from http://www.91files.com/?N3F0QGQPWMDGPBRN0QA8

Comment: What is the purpose of the PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); line ? I never use this one. Your log4j.xml file must only be "somewhere" in your classpath.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly to find, how the log4j configuration itself is being logged. I Think this should help you alot, because some containers have their own log4j configuration.

Comment: @AntoineClaval I removed that cursed line and it worked like a charm. Man, what a ride..

Answer (score 123):

I know it's a bit late to answer this question, and maybe you already found the solution, but I'm posting the solution I found (after I googled a lot) so it may help a little:

1. Put log4j.properties under WEB-INF\classes of the project as mentioned previously in this thread.
2. Put log4j-xx.jar under WEB-INF\lib
3. Test if log4j was loaded: add `-Dlog4j.debug` @ the end of your java options of tomcat

Hope this will help.

rgds

Comment: Use the 'run' command to get tomcat in foreground; you can pass in java options via the command line. Also, the -x option to bash is useful to see what exactly happens to your options: JAVA_OPTS=-Dlog4j.debug bash -x /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run

Comment: You save my day! In case of log4j2 put log4j2.xml under WEB-INF\classes

Answer (score 59):

As already stated, log4j.properties should be in a directory included in the classpath, I want to add that in a mavenized project a good place can be `src/main/resources/log4j.properties`

Answer (score 31):

You can specify config file location with VM argument -Dlog4j.configuration="file:/C:/workspace3/local/log4j.properties"

Comment: is it file:/ or file:/// or just /path/to/file on a unix system?

Comment: For windows it's just file:/  , I'm guessing unix is the same

Comment: This is imo the only answer that takes that takes multiple environments into account that have different log levels.

Comment: On macOS, in Liberty Server's jvm.options don't use quotes and use file:///

Comment: Just an update which might help save some frustration: if you're using log4j2, the name of the argument has been changed to ```log4j.configurationFile```

Answer (score 26):

You have to put it in the root directory, that corresponds to your execution context.

Example:

```
    MyProject
       src
           MyClass.java
           log4j.properties
```

If you start executing from a different project, you need to have that file in the project used for starting the execution. For example, if a different project holds some JUnit tests, it needs to have also its log4j.properties file.

---

I suggest using log4j.xml instead of the log4j.properties. You have more options, get assistance from your IDE and so on...

Comment: in example, I almost put it every directory. but it is not helpful to Glassfish deploy project, because GF don't copy properties to the correct directory. It seems GF do lose it.

Comment: actually, I think the problem is from auto-deploy of netbeans. I try to deploy by war file in admin console, it's ok. I don't know if I was right. If I was right, why netbeans don't deploy these files when auto-deploy the project.

Comment: it worked ! but doesn't it inelegant ... it think it's better placed in a "resource" kind of folder.

Answer (score 21):

For a Maven Based Project keep your log4j.properties in src/main/resources. Nothing else to do!

Comment: That's it, and it's the same for other properties files like XMLConfiguration in Maven Projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you put log4j.properties inside src, you don't need to use the statement -

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

It will be taken automatically as the properties file is in the classpath.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(getClass().getResource("/controlador/log4j.properties"));
```

Answer (score 9):

The file should be located in the WEB-INF/classes directory.
This directory structure should be packaged within the war file.

Comment: in theory, it is the answer, but the problem is log4j.properties is losted when glassfish deploy war file.

Comment: It should be in WEB-INF/classes and packaged within the war file

Comment: @mono - at least in the downloadable archive there is NO log4j.properties in web/WEB-INF/classes.  Martin is right, that's where it should be.

Comment: The trick is, you put it in your src folder, (Your root source folder), in the process of Building your code, the file is transferred to the classes folder automatically...

Answer (score 7):

My IDE is NetBeans. I put log4j.property file as shown in the pictures

Root

[image: project's root folder]

Web

[image: web folder]

WEB-INF

[image: WEB-INF folder]

To use this property file you should to write this code:

```
package example;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import javax.servlet.*;
public class test {

public static ServletContext context;
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("example/test");

public test() {

        String homeDir = context.getRealPath("/");
        File propertiesFile = new File(homeDir, "WEB-INF/log4j.properties");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(propertiesFile.toString());
        log.info("This is a test");
    }
}
```

You can define **static ServletContext context** from another JSP file.
Example:

```
test.context = getServletContext(); 
test sample = new test();
```

Now you can use log4j.property file in your projects.

Answer (score 5):

A few technically correct specific answers already provided but in general, it can be anywhere on the runtime classpath, i.e. wherever classes are sought by the JVM.

This could be the /src dir in Eclipse or the WEB-INF/classes directory in your deployed app, but it's best to be aware of the classpath concept and why the file is placed in it, don't just treat WEB-INF/classes as a "magic" directory.

Answer (score 5):

I've spent a great deal of time to figure out why the **log4j.properties** file is not seen. 
Then I noticed it was visible for the project only when it was in both **MyProject/target/classes/** and **MyProject/src/main/resources** folders. 
Hope it'll be useful to somebody. 
PS: The project was maven-based.

Answer (score 3):

I found that Glassfish by default is looking at [Glassfish install location]\glassfish\domains[your domain]\ as the default working directory...  you can drop the log4j.properties file in this location and initialize it in your code using PropertyConfigurator as previously mentioned...

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
System.out.println("Current working directory is " + props.getProperty("user.dir"));
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your standard project setup will have a project structure something like:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
```

You place log4j.properties inside the resources folder, you can create the resources folder if one does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this is correct way.But it solved my problem.
put log4j.properties file in "project folder"/config and use PropertyConfigurator.configure("config//log4j.properties");

it will works with IDE but not when run the jar file yourself.
when you run the jar file by yourself just copy the log4j.properties file in to the folder that jar file is in.when the jar and property file in same directory it runs well.

Answer (score 1):

Put log4j.properties in classpath.
Here is the 2 cases that will help you to identify the proper location-
 1. For web application the classpath is /WEB-INF/classes.

```
\WEB-INF      
    classes\
        log4j.properties
```

2. To test from main / unit test the classpath is source directory

   ```
   \Project\
      src\
         log4j.properties
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it:

**Way1:** If you are trying in maven project **without Using PropertyConfigurator**

First: 
 check for resources directory at scr/main

```
  if available,
       then: create a .properties file and add all configuration details.
  else
       then: create a directory named resources and a file with .properties     
write your configuration code/details.
```

**follows the screenshot:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Way2:** If you are trying with Properties file for java/maven project **Use PropertyConfigurator**

Place properties file anywhere in project and give the correct path.
say: **src/javaLog4jProperties/log4j.properties**

static{

```
 PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/javaLog4jProperties/log4j.properties");
```

}

[image]

**Way3:** If you are trying with xml on java/maven project **Use DOMConfigurator**

Place properties file anywhere in project and give correct path.
say: **src/javaLog4jProperties/log4j.xml**

static{

```
 DOMConfigurator.configure("src/javaLog4jProperties/log4j.xml");
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked when I put the file inside the resources folder.
Also, it was a war file for my project. My recommendation is to ensure that the name of the file is log4j.properties, as my project didn't recognize "log4j2.properties"

[image: log4j.properties in src/main/resources]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've just experienced this problem in a stardard Java project structure as follows:

```
\myproject
    \src
    \libs
    \res\log4j.properties
```

In Eclipse I need to add the res folder to build path, however, in Intellij, I need to mark the res folder as resouces as the linked screenshot shows: [right click on the res folder and mark as resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgPRL.png).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify `PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");` in your Log4J class, If you have already defined the log4j.properties in your project structure.

In case of Web Dynamic Project: -

You need to save your log4j.properties under WebContent -> WEB-INF -> log4j.properties

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Open `spark-shell`

Then type `System.getenv("SPARK_CONF_DIR")`

That will print where your `log4j.properties` should go.