# Where is the correct location to put Log4j.properties in an Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, classpath

Where in my Eclipse project should I add the `log4j.properties` file so that it will work as intended?

Comment: Your question is far too vague. Generally it is added to classpath. Right click on project, build path.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

you can add it any where you want, when you run your project, configure the classpath and add the location of the log4j.properties files by clicking on: 
Run->Run Configuration -> [classpath tab] -> click on user Entries -> Advanced -> Select Add Folder -> select the location of your log4j.properties file

and then -> OK -> run

and it should get loaded

Comment: And what happens if my project is a library? and I put log4j.properties in the source root, then my library users using log4j too will catch this log4j.properties maybe overriding theirs or at least it could create confusion

Comment: @jaime I have the same problem, I have my project using 2 of my libraries, where each of the libraries and the main project have log4j.properties inside of source root, and now when I run the main project it takes wrong log4j.properties from one of the libraries. What's the best way to fix that?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel typically you shouldn't have log4j properties bundled in your library. The users of your library should be providing their logging configuration, ideally I would say you should give your users a mean to inject their preferred logging strategy, and you code your logging against an interface. It's not just the log4j config file, it could be the whole logger implementation etc.

Comment: I have ended up placing a reference `log4j.properties` in my libraries at `/org/example/mylibrary/log4j.properties`. This way it won't be catched automatically by my library users, but can still be used if their JVM is configured with `-Dlog4j.configuration=...` or at least can serve them as reference for their own `log4j.properties`.

Answer (score 36):

The safest way IMO is to point at the file in your run/debug config

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:mylogging.properties
```

! Be aware: when using the eclipse launch configurations the specification of the `file:` protocol is mandatory.

In this way the logger will not catch any logging.properties that come before in the classpath nor the default one in the JDK.

Also, consider actually use the log4j.xml which has a richer expression syntax and will allow more things (log4j.xml tahe precedence over log4j.properties.

Comment: More like -Dlog4j.configuration="file:path/to/log4j.properties"

Answer (score 12):

Add the log4j.properties file to the runtime class path of the project.
Some people add this to the root of the source tree (so that it gets copied to the root of the compiled classes).

**Edit:**
If your project is a maven project,
you can put the log4j.properties in the src/main/resources folder (and the src/test/resources for your unit tests).

If you have multiple environments (for example development and production),
want different logging for each environment,
and want to deploy the same jar (or war, or ear) file to each environment
(as in one build for all environments)
then store the log4j.properties file outside of the jar file and put it in the class path for each environment (configurable by environment).
Historically, I would include some known directory in each environment in the classpath and deploy environment specific stuff there.
For example,
~tomcat_user/localclasspath where ~tomcat_user is the home directory of the user that will be running the tomcat instance to which my war file will be deployed.

Comment: Beware if a jar in the classpath contains its own log4j.properties

Comment: @AlainPannetier I wonder how to solve this problem? Because to my understanding if I put log4j.properties on classpath, it WILL automatically include it into src/ root?

Comment: yes, that is why I said "...add this to the root of the source tree..."

Comment: Can you please help me with a related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278607/using-simple-log4j-properties-in-my-java-code

Answer (score 10):

The best way is to create special source folder named `resources` and use it for all resource including log4j.properties. So, just put it there.

On the Java Resources folder that was automatically created by the Dynamic Web Project, right click and add a new Source Folder and name it 'resources'.  Files here will then be exported to the war file to the classes directory

Comment: Can you please help me with a related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278607/using-simple-log4j-properties-in-my-java-code

Answer (score 9):

If you have a library and you want to append the log4j:

1. Create a folder named "resources" in your projet.
2. Create a .properties file named log4j
3. Set properties in log4j.properties file
4. Push right button in the project and go to properties->Java Build Path and, finally, go to the "Source" tab.
5. Push Add folder and search the "resources" folder created in step 1.
6. Finish.

(I have assumed that you have the log4j library added.)

PD: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 5):

This question is already answered [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it)

The classpath never includes specific files. It includes directories and jar files. So, put that file in a directory that is in your `classpath`.

`Log4j` properties aren't (normally) used in developing apps (unless you're debugging Eclipse itself!). So what you really want to to build the executable Java app (Application, WAR, EAR or whatever) and include the `Log4j` properties in the runtime classpath.

Comment: Can you please help me with a related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278607/using-simple-log4j-properties-in-my-java-code

Answer (score 3):

Put `log4j.properties` in the runtime classpath.

This [forum](https://www.coderanch.com/t/106042/vc/Eclipse-add-log-properties-classpath) shows some posts about possible ways to do it.

Comment: Can you please help me with a related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278607/using-simple-log4j-properties-in-my-java-code

Answer (score 1):

In general I put it in a special folder "res" or "resources as already said, but after for the web application, I copy the `log4j.properties` with the ant task to the WEB-INF/classes directory. It is the same like letting the file at the root of the src/ folder but generally  I prefer to see it in a dedicated folder.

With Maven, the usual place to put is in the folder `src/main/resources` as answered in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6757339/628006).
All resources there will go to your build in the root classpath (e.g. `target/classes/`)

If you want a powerful logger, you can have also a look to [slf4j library](https://www.slf4j.org) which is a logger facade and can use the log4j implementation behind.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding out that the location of the log4j.properties file depends on the type of Eclipse project.

Specifically, for an Eclipse Dynamic Web Project, most of the answers that involve adding the log4j.properties to the war file do not actually add the properties file in the correct location, especially for Tomcat/Apache.

Here is some of my research and my solution to the issue (again specifically for a Dynamic Web Project running on Tomcat/Apache 6.0)

- Please refer to this article around how Tomcat will load classes.  It's different than the  normal class loader for Java.  (https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath)  Note that it only looks in two places in the war file, WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib.
- Note that with a Dynamic Web Project, it is not wise to store your .properties file in the build/../classes directory, as this directory is wiped whenever you clean-build your project.
- Tomcat does not handle .property files in the WEB-INF/lib location.
- You cannot store the log4j.properties file in the src directory, as Eclipse abstracts that directory away from your view.
- The one way I have found to resolve this is to alter the build and add an additional directory that will eventually load into the WEB-INF/classes directory in the war file.  Specifically....

(1) Right click your project in the project explorer, select 'New'->'Folder'.  You can name the folder anything, but the standard in this case is 'resources'.  The new folder should appear at the root level of your project.

(2) Move the log4j.properties file into this new folder.

(3) Right click the project again, and select 'Build-Path'->'Configure Build Path'.  Select the 'Sources' tab.  Click the 'Add Folder' button.  Browse to find your new folder you created in step (1) above.  Select 'OK'.

(4) Once back to the eclipse Project Explorer view, note that the folder has now moved to the 'Java Resources' area (ie it's no longer at the root due to eclipse presentation abstraction).

(5) Clean build your project.

(6) To validate that the .properties file now exists in WEB-INF/classes in your war file, export a war file to an easy location (right click Project -> Export -> War file) and checkout the contents.  Note that the log4j.properties file now appears in the WEB-INF/classes.

(7) Promote your project to Tomcat/Apache and note that log4j now works.

Now that log4j works, start logging, solve world problems, take some time off, and enjoy a tasty adult beverage.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to have the log4j.properties packaged with your project deployable -- that is a bad idea, as other posters have mentioned.

Find the root Tomcat installation that Eclipse is pointing to when it runs your application, and add the log4j.properties file in the proper place there. For Tomcat 7, the right place is

${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib

Answer (score 0):

For a normal (non maven and non web) java project in eclipse.

1. Create a "source" folder with new options and with any name (as a standard we can name it as resources) under the project directory
2. push the log4j.properties file to this "source" folder.
3. Build and run the application.