# Log4J Tomcat Web App Properties File Location

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, logging, log4j

I have a web app running under Tomcat 7 in Eclipse that uses its own instance of log4J (not Tomcat's).  The logger is having problems locating logger.properties.  Does anyone know where I should place the properties file so its picked up by the web app?

I've tried:
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes
WEB-INF/lib
WebContent
WebContent/web_app_root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that you need it at [WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081316/where-is-the-correct-location-to-put-log4j-properties-in-an-eclipse-project) within your web application. Hope that helps...

Comment: Here's a tip.  If you add -Dlog4j.debug to your java run time log4J will display info about what its doing and where its looking for files.  For a Tomcat environment add this top the arguments of your launch configuration in the Server properties dialog.