# Where to place log4j.xml file in a non Maven Project

Tags: java, log4j

I have my log4j.xml file stored in the project directory but i am getting following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (p1.Employee).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more 
info.
```

When i palced it in the bin folder Everything works fine. But i dont check in the bin folder in the code repository so i dont want to place it there.

I dont want to use DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml") as well

Below is my Project Stucture.

[image]

Comment: Maven `resources` directory is under classpath, so you should place it inside `src`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the correct location to put Log4j.properties in an Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081316/where-is-the-correct-location-to-put-log4j-properties-in-an-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 1):

In a normal Java Project, you can place a log4j configuration file, i.e., a `log4j.properties` or a `log4j.xml`, in a `resources` directory. The resources directory should be on the same level as `src`. Putting it here, will allow log4j to use the configuration file automatically.

Otherwise, you can set the log4j configuration file to use via a VM option by doing something like:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/log4j.xml
```

In your case, if you want to place it in the TrailProject project directory, you can do

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/TrailProject/log4j.xml
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but I have already put it on the same level as src .

Comment: What is on the same level as `src`? The `resources` directory or the configuration file?

Comment: I have the configuration file which is at same level as src. If i add the resources folder (with the configuration file) then i need to add this resources folder to class path in eclipse. But then person who checkc out my code will have to again add the resources folder to classpath . is it?

Comment: How do people use your code? I'm under the impression that your code will be made an executable JAR.

Comment: No. This is test automation code. And hence we are directly running using test Ng.xml file .

Comment: If it is NetBeans project file path must be like that: `Dlog4j.configuration=resources/log4j.properties`. In addition, I added `resources`  directory as a source directory in project options.

Answer (score 0):

As per the maven java project folder structure, the ideal path to put the config.xml would be in `/src/main/resources` directory, so for a non maven project you would put it in an equivalent `/resources` directory.