# log4j postgres in Java EE

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jakarta-ee, log4j

After many search on the subject I finally think the solution of my problem is to ask you.

So my problem is in the way to create logs on my web application utilisation.

I found the log4j java library but I don't understand how that works..

Where I have to create configuration file ?

Where and how to make reference on it?

Can I create a class that connect to postgres and insertin log my three parameters?

Here is what I found on the net :

**./src/log4j/log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootCategory = FATAL, CONSOLE
# definition de l'appender console
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern = %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

# definition de l'appender JDBC
log4j.appender.JDBC=org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.JDBC.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# appender pour base postgresql
log4j.appender.JDBC.dbclass=org.postgresql.Driver
# parametres de la base
log4j.appender.JDBC.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/baseSQL
log4j.appender.JDBC.username=user
log4j.appender.JDBC.password=password
# requete sql qui decoupe le message suivant les barres verticales et fait l'insert dans la table
log4j.appender.JDBC.sql=INSERT INTO logs (id, user, info1, info2, timestamp) VALUES (nextval('sequence_logs'), split_part('@MSG@','|',1), split_part('@MSG@','|',2), split_part('@MSG@','|',3), '@TIMESTAMP@')

#declaration des loggers de l'application
log4j.logger.paquetage.de.mon.appli=FATAL, CONSOLE
log4j.logger.loggerDB=INFO,JDBC
# definition de non additivite des loggers
log4j.additivity.loggerDB=false
```

**src/log4j/LogsInfos.java**

```
package log4j;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public final class LogsInfos {

    /** Declaration du Logger DB. */
    private static Logger loggerDB = Logger.getLogger("loggerDB");

    /**
     * Enregistre le log.
     * @param param parametres du log
     */
    public static void enregistreLog(String user, String action, String sujet) {
//      Date date=new Date();
        if (loggerDB.isInfoEnabled()) {
            // creation du message final
            final String log = new StringBuffer(user).append(action).append(sujet).toString();
            // envoi du log au logger base
            loggerDB.info(log);
        }
    }
}
```

**the call in my package**

```
LogsInfos.enregistreLog((String)session.getAttribute("cn"),"Suppression",personne.getCn());
```

Can I use the object of my choice?

This code is the solution? if it is, where I have to call the configuration file?

EDIT:
This is the console error message on execution:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.jdbcplus.JDBCAppender
...
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "JDBC".
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (loggerDB).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing jdbcappender.jar in your classpath. I think you are looking for [this one](http://www.mannhaupt.com/danko/projects/index.html). Or you can go with the [official JDBCAppender](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm), but I'm not sure if is powerful engough for your needs.

> Where I have to create configuration file ?

Most people create it [at the application root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it), but I'm sure yours is being read just fine.

> Where and how to make reference on it?

You really dont need to, if the configuration file and the libraries are in the classpath, all you need is a Logger instance.

> Can I create a class that connect to postgres and insertin log my three parameters?

Yes. You are in the right track. Just put the required jars in the classpath and make sure your `log4j.appender.JDBC.sql` line works. You will use the Logger class methods which will take care of everything for you.

Cheers,

Comment: Just saw your two other questions. I think you will need to separate your parameters with pipes ("|") for your configuration sql line to work. And I think it is pretty safe to replace your StringBuffer with a faster StringBuilder (unless this code is multithreaded somehow)

Comment: `Can I use the object of my choice?`
Yes, but since your are sending them to a StringBuffer, make sure they correctly override the toString() method, or your output may not be what you are expecting. Or maybe i misinterpreted you question.