# How get WEB-INF folder path in java JAX-WS app

Tags: java, resources, web-inf, applicationcontext

I have a java webservice application with java bean's.
How i can determine full path to file in WEB-INF directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this for ?
One way to do this is from your jsp/servlet through `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("web-app/WEB-INF/...")`
Also, if you are trying to use a .wsdl file on a client, you are better off specifying the uri of your server rather than the physical address.

Comment: I use a java lib, which use external config file. Lib call from Stateless Bean not from jsp or servlet.

Comment: I found workaround, but question still open. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it   "Glassfish by default is looking at [Glassfish install location]\glassfish\domains[your domain]\ as the default working directory"  So i put config files in this directory and make relative path.