# Where to put log4j.properties in a GWT web app

Tags: gwt, tomcat, ant, log4j, classpath

I have the log4j.properties and another .properties file under src and it works deployed in gwt dev mode. To build the war to launch to tomcat I use an ant script that compiles the .java classes and puts them in a JAR file. The JAR file gets copied into the WEB-INF folder in the war file.

The app runs fine when I don't use log4j but it can't find the properties file when I attempt to use log4j. All of the answers I see say WEB-INF/classes, but my project doesn't have a WEB-INF/classes directory, instead the JAR file that was copied to WEB-INF contains my projects classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put log4j.properties (or log4j.xml) file into directory or JAR that is considered by your servlet-container as resource in Classpath.

So, simply create WEB-INF/classes directory and put it there, or pack it into your JAR.

See also [Where should I put the log4j.properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it) - it could be useful.