# Configure log4j.properties in Intellij

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, log4j

I have problem configure log4j properties.
I used to use code to configure logger.
But, now I am getting the no appenders could be found WARN from groovyx.net.http.RESTClient which I can't change the code. The WARN is below:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (groovyx.net.http.RESTClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

So I tried to use the log4j.properties file by default to setup the appenders. But, I don't know where I should put the log4j.properties file. I add the -Dlog4j.debug as JVM option and run the test. I am getting the below information:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a6eb38a.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a6eb38a class loader.  
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a6eb38a.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@a6eb38a class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
```

I am using IntelliJ and running a Spock test.
Any answer will be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your log4j config file should be placed in source root.

In IDEA it may be resource folder.

Look at: [Where should I put the log4j.properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it)

For Groovy it all the same.

Comment: Cool. I put it under resource and it worked. I was reading from other place saying it need to be under source/test source which seems to be not true. Thank you.

Comment: @user1947415 If you have a separate log configuration for test enviroment, you can have test-config in test folder. It's up to you.

Comment: Yes, the folder name does not matter. The point is to mark it as resource NOT source in IntelliJ. I have tried marked the folder that contained the log4j.properties files as source and test source before I post this question. But, that doesn't work.

Comment: @user1947415 There was no such difference in earlyer versions of IDE, there was no "Mark as Resource" possibility. I'll check it later.

Answer (score -2):

In intellij, you can assign a path to the configuration file as follows:

1. Open the edit configuration dialog box
2. Click on the logs tab
3. Click on the plus sign to add a path to your properties/xml file. You can add an alias for this configuration.
4. Apply.

To check if your log4j config file has been loaded, you can add the VM Option under run/edit configuration as -Dlog4j.debug. Using this argument log4j will log into the console steps relating to the process of loading the file.

Comment: After much frustration, it turns out the path in a (not spring) java project must be project_name/src/main/resources/log4j.xml  (or properties)

Comment: After much frustration, it turns out the path in a (not spring) java project must be project_name/src/main/resources/log4j.xml  (or properties)