# Log4j log append to file name dependent on day - config

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j

I'm fairly new to log4j and I would like to set up automatic logging of anything output to the console, like errors, or info messages for a web app running on my local server.

How would I set up my xml and/or properties file to do this? What I really am looking for is that each day a new log file be created in a directory (Ex: /mylogs/app-log-01-08-2014.log)

I've begun like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<!-- general application log -->

<appender name="BarLogFile" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="my-changing-file-name.log" /> ->>> how does this change
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" /> ->>> should INFO be Console here?
</appender> 

<logger name="what-goes-here?">
    <appender-ref ref="something-here"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
</root>
```

Also, where in a web project does the xml file go? WEB-INF?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for what is known as "daily rolling log files", configuration is shown [here](http://www.codejava.net/coding/configure-log4j-for-creating-daily-rolling-log-files). As for the web project, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523730/3080094) answer.

On a side node, you might want to learn about [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html) as alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know what this was called, so I couldn't search for it. Now I now. Thanks again.