# Using Log4J In Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

I am trying to use Log4J in Netbeans, however I am having a very hard time understanding the tutorials. Many of them say "do this" and assume I know what they are talking about. I do not. If you would, I'd like step-by-step instructions on where to find the correct libraries for Log4J, where to put them in a project, and an example program using Log4J.

Answer (score 8):

### log4j 2.x

Similar to below, but the name of the filename needs to be `log4j2.properties`. (Also note that old examples of log4j.properties configuration don't actually seem to do anything useful in Log4j 2, so make sure to copy your initial configuration from a tutorial dedicated to Log4j 2, and not the older v1.)

Thanks [@bobulous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1515834/bobulous)

### log4j 1.x

If you get `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger` message, then
it is most likely that you haven't included the log4j.properties file in your
project.  Here's a screenshot of how you should include it in NetBeans.

[image: log4j.properties NetBeans]

Comment: Just to save others ninety minutes of irate frustration, do note that if you're using Log4j **2** then the name of the filename needs to be `log4j2.properties`. (Also note that old examples of log4j.properties configuration don't actually seem to do anything useful in Log4j 2, so make sure to copy your initial configuration from a tutorial dedicated to Log4j 2, and not the older v1.)

Answer (score 3):

[This very comprehensive working example for log4j2](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j-2-properties-file-configuration-example/) has nearly everything, duplicated here incase the link breaks

To get a working example, create a **new maven java application** in netbeans (or any IDE)

> New Project -> Maven -> Java Application

In your new maven project there is a **pom.xml** under 'project files' in netbeans, you need to add this dependency:

> I tested this with log4j version 2.11.1, check for latest [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core)

```
   ... 
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.11.1</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Create a **src/main/resources/log4j2.properties** (this exact path and name is required)

> you can later customize the print layout using [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) as a reference

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold
filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Create a new class: **Log4j2HelloWorldExample.java**

```
package com.howtodoinjava.log4j2.examples;   

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


public class Log4j2HelloWorldExample {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Log4j2HelloWorldExample.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.debug("Debug Message Logged !!!");
        LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged !!!");
        LOGGER.error("Error Message Logged !!!", new NullPointerException("NullError"));
    }
}
```

When you run the class you will get his **output**:

```
 2016-06-16 13:41:27 DEBUG Log4j2HelloWorldExample:12 - Debug Message Logged !!!
 2016-06-16 13:41:27 INFO  Log4j2HelloWorldExample:13 - Info Message Logged !!!
 2016-06-16 13:41:27 ERROR Log4j2HelloWorldExample:14 - Error Message Logged !!!
 java.lang.NullPointerException: NullError
     at com.howtodoinjava.log4j2.examples.Log4j2HelloWorldExample.main(Log4j2HelloWorldExample.java:14)
    [classes/:?]
```

---

If the above example works stand alone, but not when you integrate it into your project there might be some dependency interference

Run `mvn dependency:tree` and exclude all interfering log4j dependencies, I needed to exclude these:

```
<exclusion>
    <!-- 
        [INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
        [INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.16:compile
    -->
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</exclusion>
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

To bridge existing slf4j code to my newly added log4j2, I had to include this dependency I found [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/java-logging/slf4j-with-log4j2.html)

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

I still saw this:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I also needed to ensure the log4j2.property file had my OS specific line endings, I was using Cygwin to create property files and running netbeans from windows and it failed to find appenders due to the property file all being read as a single line by Windows

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm -

Download the jar from here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html

Add this file in your path:

log4j.properties

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /usr/home/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Here is the location output of the file!
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Then run this:

log4jExample.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;

public class log4jExample{
  /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                      log4jExample.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args)
                throws IOException,SQLException{

     log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
     log.info("Hello this is an info message");
  }
}
```

Comment: Well I got farther than usual, but i recieved this after compiling, building, and then running the program: run:
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (log4jexample.Log4jExample).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: I think that means you haven't added the .properties file properly in your classpath.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it?rq=1

Comment: Well the error is gone now, but replaced with a new one: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. It's referring to this part of the code: static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4J.class.getName());

Comment: What is your class called when you run the program?

Comment: The class is called log4jExample

Comment: change static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4J.class.getName()); to static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(log4jExample.class.getName()); . And if that doesn't work it's possible that your jar file cannot be found.

Comment: Part of the problem was that some other projects I had contained similar names and were getting mixed around. I redid your example and have made sure that log4j-1.2.17.jar is in the projects libraries. In the project Source Packages log4j.properties is right next to log4jExample.java. I'm getting an error saying that the appenders can't be found so I likely have .properties in the wrong spot.