# Log4j installation and configuration

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I tried to follow [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_configuration.htm) tutorial in order to install and use `log4j` in my application, but it seems like this tutorial is outdated.

First of all, contrary to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_installation.htm), on the official [page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html) there are no apache-log4j-x.x.x.tar.gz files, instead there are apache-log4j-x.x.x-bin.tar.gz and apache-log4j-x.x.x-src.tar.gz.

So, I downloaded both archives, but their contents has nothing to do with

```
apache-log4j-1.2.15/tests/input/
apache-log4j-1.2.15/tests/input/xml/
apache-log4j-1.2.15/tests/src/
apache-log4j-1.2.15/tests/src/java/
apache-log4j-1.2.15/tests/src/java/org/
....
```

And finally, the tutorial is addressing log4j.properties file, however, nothing is said about where it is stored or should it be created manually and so on. I hope, someone can provide a fresher tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: Whats about this: [log4j](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/log4j-tutorial/)

Comment: This tutorial refers to http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/ page which dates back to 2012-05-13. Not sure, whether it is fresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first started learning about `log4j`, I read first about it's architecture from here [Log4j introduction](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html). There you will also find a download link to the log4j jars required for using this API.

Regarding the `log4j.properties` file, you will have to create it yourself. I'll add bellow a sample of it

```
#Define the root logger with the appender FILE
```

log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

## Set the appender named FILE to be a File Appender

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/log.out

## log4j.appender.FILE.threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true

## Define the layout for FILE appender

log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

## Define the CONSOLE Appender to be a Console Appender

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

## Define the layout for the CONSOLE Appender

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

Here a simple test class`public class TestLog4j {

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("newLogger");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Hello World");
}`
```

}

Comment: Should log4j.properties file be in the same directory as those two log4j jars (api and core jar)? Or should it be in the same directory as the running program?

Comment: It should work if you put it in the same directory where you have the class holding the main method. If you are using an IDE like Intellij you could create a folder where to store all kind of property files and mark it as a resource folder (for testing purposes).

Comment: See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it