# How to configure log4j in a Spring Mvc application configured with Java Annotations and using a log4j.properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I'm working on a Maven Web application using `Spring MVC 4.2.5.RELEASE`, I'm using `Netbeans` IDE with `GlassFishSErver 4.1`, I want to use `log4j 1.2.17` so I created a log4j.properties file but it seems like my properties file it's not being found because I get the following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I configured my Spring application using java annotations here is my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"config", "controllers"})
public class ConfigMVC extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
```

}

here is my WebInitializer

```
public class WebInicializar implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ConfigMVC.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");
    }
}
```

and here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String paginaSinMap(ModelMap map) {

    logger.info("This is an info log entry");
    logger.error("This is an error log entry");

    return "myPage";
}
```

and here it's my `log4j.properties`

```
# LOG4J configuration
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Appender1, Appender2

log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=D:/Logs/SpringMVC.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

and I put this log4j.properties in my resources folder, here is my project structure

EDIT: I didn't mention that my project is a maven web application using spring 
and this is my project structure

```
MyWebAppProjectName
--Web Pages
  --WEB-INF
    --jsp
         index.jsp
    --resources
      --js
         js.js
      --css
         site.css
      log4j.properties
--Source Packages
  --config
      ConfigMVC.java
      WebInitializaer.java
  --controllers
      HomeController.java
--Test Packages
--Other Resources
  --src/main/resources
    --default package
--Dependencies
--Java Dependencies
--Project FIles
```

So I put the log4j.properties in the `Other Resources/src/main/resources` and when I did this Netbeans created a `default Package` with the file inside like this `default package/log4j-properties` and it worked the logs starting to appear in the output and everything worked fine as expected.

I tried to create a package named `Log4jResource` inside this path `src/main/resources` but when I did this it stopped to work and the error showed again, so it's there a way to put this file in that folder but without having to use `default package` that NetBeans creates when I put the folder in there.

I tried doing refactor rename the default package but it shows me this error `Module JPA Refactoring threw java.lang.NullPointerException. Please report a bug against JPA Refactoring module and attach your var/log/messages.log.`

My final project structure looks like this

```
MyWebAppProjectName
--Web Pages
  --WEB-INF
    --jsp
         index.jsp
    --resources
      --js
         js.js
      --css
         site.css
      log4j.properties
--Source Packages
  --config
      ConfigMVC.java
      WebInitializaer.java
  --controllers
      HomeController.java
--Test Packages
--Other Resources
  --src/main/resources
    --default package
      --log4j.properties
--Dependencies
--Java Dependencies
--Project FIles
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the log4j.properties file to ./WEB-INF/.  Your Spring Resources handler is certainly ok with looking in ./WEB-INF/resources/.  I don't believe log4j knows anything about spring, nor does log4j care about spring.  Log4j is going to look in the classpath for a properties file unless you expicitly tell log4j to look elsewhere.

I think right now, you've only told spring where to look for things.

Comment: I put the file in ./WEB-INF/ but still it doesn't work, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the invalid placement of the log4j.properties file that's breaking your expectations.
You could have a look at the answers presented in this stack article about [log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it)

Comment: Did the -Dlog4j.debug reveal anything as Filip suggested in this post?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/log4j-properties-file-where-to-put-it