# Where should I put my log4j2.xml in my WAR file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, log4j2

I uses Log4j 1.2.15 & 1.2.17 for a long time. But since its DailyRollingFileAppender option got bug that cause log won't rolls sometimes in 1.2, so I'm trying to immigrating to Log4j2.

Since I got no exp on Log4j2, so things don't goes smooth. I put my `log4j2.xml` under `/WEB-INF` and added following lines into `web.xml` in my Eclipse.

```
    ...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Then I export my project into WAR, and deploy it on Websphere. It show me an error.

```
[2017/6/8   14:00:15:702 CST] 000000c4 SystemErr     R ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485987/where-should-i-put-the-log4j-properties-file)

If you are using Maven in your project, consider the answer by stivlo in that question, and place your config file under src/main/resources.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I missed an "2" on my title. But I'm not looking for where to put conf file about log4j1.

Comment: It's the same place.

Comment: Oh, I thought that log4jConfiguration define is start from WEB-INF. got it, thanks