# Problems deploying kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, deployment, jbpm, guvnor, kie

I have some problems deployng kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7.
I followed Michael Anstis' guide (README) but the application give mi some problems.

I attach the log.

```
mag 13, 2014 9:46:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Informazioni: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
mag 13, 2014 9:46:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Informazioni: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
mag 13, 2014 9:46:33 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
Informazioni: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
mag 13, 2014 9:46:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
mag 13, 2014 9:46:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Informazioni: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
mag 13, 2014 9:46:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Informazioni: Initialization processed in 4380 ms
mag 13, 2014 9:46:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Informazioni: Starting service Catalina
mag 13, 2014 9:46:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Informazioni: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
mag 13, 2014 9:46:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Informazioni: Deploying web application archive C:\Eclipse2\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7.war
mag 13, 2014 9:46:35 AM bitronix.tm.integration.tomcat55.BTMLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
Informazioni: Starting Bitronix Transaction Manager
mag 13, 2014 9:46:35 AM bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager logVersion
Informazioni: Bitronix Transaction Manager version 2.1.4
mag 13, 2014 9:46:35 AM bitronix.tm.Configuration buildServerIdArray
Avvertenza: cannot get this JVM unique ID. Make sure it is configured and you only use ASCII characters. Will use IP address instead (unsafe for production usage!).
mag 13, 2014 9:46:35 AM bitronix.tm.Configuration buildServerIdArray
Informazioni: JVM unique ID: <192.168.88.90>
mag 13, 2014 9:46:35 AM bitronix.tm.recovery.Recoverer run
Informazioni: recovery committed 0 dangling transaction(s) and rolled back 0 aborted transaction(s) on 0 resource(s) [] (restricted to serverId '192.168.88.90')
mag 13, 2014 9:47:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
Informazioni: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/i18n-1.0 is already defined
mag 13, 2014 9:47:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
Avvertenza: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: no resource registered with uniqueName 'jdbc/jbpm', available resources: []
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error listenerStart
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Context [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] startup failed due to previous errors
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] appears to have started a thread named [pool-4-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] appears to have started a thread named [pool-7-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] appears to have started a thread named [org.uberfire.backend.server.IOWatchServiceNonDotImpl(WatchService{FileSystem=git://localhost:9418/jbpm-playground
ssh://localhost:8001/jbpm-playground})] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] appears to have started a thread named [org.uberfire.backend.server.IOWatchServiceNonDotImpl(WatchService{FileSystem=git://localhost:9418/uf-playground
ssh://localhost:8001/uf-playground})] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] appears to have started a thread named [Git-Daemon-Accept] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] appears to have started a thread named [IOServiceIndexedImpl(WatchService{FileSystem=git://localhost:9418/jbpm-playground
ssh://localhost:8001/jbpm-playground})] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] appears to have started a thread named [IOServiceIndexedImpl(WatchService{FileSystem=git://localhost:9418/uf-playground
ssh://localhost:8001/uf-playground})] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.jboss.errai.config.util.ClassScanner$1] (value [org.jboss.errai.config.util.ClassScanner$1@7d533f22]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [true]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
Grave: The web application [/kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.jboss.solder.servlet.beanManager.ServletContextAttributeProvider$1] (value [org.jboss.solder.servlet.beanManager.ServletContextAttributeProvider$1@64561175]) and a value of type [org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade] (value [org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@4e944bc9]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
mag 13, 2014 9:48:27 AM bitronix.tm.integration.tomcat55.BTMLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
Informazioni: Shutting down Bitronix Transaction Manager
mag 13, 2014 9:48:27 AM bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager shutdown
Informazioni: shutting down Bitronix Transaction Manager
mag 13, 2014 9:48:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Informazioni: Deploying web application directory C:\Eclipse2\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\docs
mag 13, 2014 9:48:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Informazioni: Deploying web application directory C:\Eclipse2\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\examples
mag 13, 2014 9:48:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Informazioni: Deploying web application directory C:\Eclipse2\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\host-manager
mag 13, 2014 9:48:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Informazioni: Deploying web application directory C:\Eclipse2\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\manager
mag 13, 2014 9:48:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
Informazioni: Deploying web application directory C:\Eclipse2\apache-tomcat-7.0.53\webapps\ROOT
mag 13, 2014 9:48:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
mag 13, 2014 9:48:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Informazioni: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
mag 13, 2014 9:48:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Informazioni: Server startup in 115456 ms
```

sorry for the trouble but I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 3):

This [post](http://bitronix-transaction-manager.10986.n7.nabble.com/problems-configuring-btm-in-tomcat-6-td1198.html) will provide the best advice.  As Ludovic identifies, your btm-config.properties file is not being read - this is apparent because of the message "cannot get this JVM unique ID" and no resources have been registered - "available resources: []".  Unfortunately, most of the documentation is not geared towards windows so there is a bit of adjustment involved.  Here is the setenv.bat file that I used, which must be placed in the tomcat_home/bin directory:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dbtm.root=%CATALINA_HOME% -Dbitronix.tm.configuration=%CATALINA_HOME%\conf\btm-config.properties -Djbpm.tsr.jndi.lookup=java:comp/env/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry -Djava.security.auth.login.config=%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\kie-wb\WEB-INF\classes\login.config -Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=jdk
```

Note that if you are using tomcat as a service then you will need to set the options using the configuration tool, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508711/tomcat-logging-while-running-as-a-windows-service/30839548#30839548).

Comment: This is the solution for windows users. Thanks for the answer ! It saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe which problems are you experiencing? based on the log that you have pasted there is not much information in there to see clearly what is the end result of those logs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the application is not deployed.

I am trying to install KIE-WB on Tomcat.
In order to reduce possible errors, I have firstly tried to deploy the 6.0.1 version, and next the last version of 6.1.
In both cases I have tried to follow the README located inside the war, but in either cases I have the same type of error.

Maybe I do not understand the exact sequences.

This is what I have done under Windows:
1 Downloaded  apache-tomcat-7.0.53.tar

1. applied the requested modifications, which I have zipped here in this file on dropbox:
   dropbox.com/s/ajshfwjmeldtlmg/modFiles.zip
   you simply copy the folder in the tomact directory.
2. Finally tried to deploy  kie-wb-distribution-wars-6.1.0-20140511.124239-177-tomcat7

The dropbox zip file is for version 6.1, but the log is the same for 6.0.1, but doing previously more modifications.

These problems come from:

issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-425
issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-406

and the read-me inside kie-wb-distribution-wars, should be a workaround, but even if I follow the instructions I still have the memory leak error.