# Tomcat on Windows, Chrome console: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200

Tags: windows, tomcat

After upgrading Tomcat on windows, Chrome is not able to pull some files.  It seems to fail when running scripts using relative paths.  Some small files return fine.

Chrome console:

```
net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200
```

Problem persists when trying several newer versions of Apache Tomcat.

For the record, I have also changed my appBase.  Problem seems to persist either way.   Default Tomcat content serves fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by opening the Tomcat Service

- Properties
- Log On
- Select local system account
- Allow service to interact with desktop (not sure this is needed?)

And is explained fully here [Tomcat Service gets installed with “Local Service” account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929708/tomcat-service-gets-installed-with-local-service-account/65636976#65636976)