# How to set level logging to DEBUG in Tomcat?

Tags: debugging, tomcat, logging, tomcat7, tomcat6

I would like to set level logging to DEBUG in tomcat but in console nevertheless only INFO and WARN output.
Could anybody tell me what's wrong?

My C:\tomcat\logging.properties:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional DEBUGrmation regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration DEBUG for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = DEBUG
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = DEBUG
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = DEBUG
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = DEBUG
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = DEBUG
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = DEBUG
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = DEBUG
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = DEBUG
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = DEBUG
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = DEBUG
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = DEBUG
#org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=DEBUG
```

Example of my log:

```
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
08.11.2010 1:06:42 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive spring-mvc-trial.war
08.11.2010 1:06:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
08.11.2010 1:06:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
08.11.2010 1:06:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
08.11.2010 1:06:46 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
08.11.2010 1:06:46 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
08.11.2010 1:06:46 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3777 ms
08.11.2010 1:09:36 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
08.11.2010 1:09:36 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
08.11.2010 1:09:37 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
08.11.2010 1:09:37 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/spring-mvc-trial] registered the JBDC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
08.11.2010 1:09:37 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/spring-mvc-trial] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
08.11.2010 1:09:38 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
08.11.2010 1:09:38 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
```

Comment: For Tomcat 8, see: [Tomcat 8 enable debug logging to list unneeded jars](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24821865/55075)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Firstly, the level name to use is `FINE`, not `DEBUG`. Let's assume for a minute that `DEBUG` is actually valid, as it makes the following explanation make a bit more sense...

In the `Handler specific properties` section, you're setting the logging level for those handlers to `DEBUG`. This means the handlers will handle any log messages with the `DEBUG` level or higher. It doesn't necessarily mean any `DEBUG` messages are actually getting passed to the handlers.

In the `Facility specific properties` section, you're setting the logging level for a few explicitly-named loggers to `DEBUG`. For those loggers, anything at level `DEBUG` or above **will** get passed to the handlers.

The default logging level is `INFO`, and apart from the loggers mentioned in the `Facility specific properties` section, all loggers will have that level.

If you want to see all `FINE` messages, add this:

```
.level = FINE
```

However, this will generate a vast quantity of log messages. It's probably more useful to set the logging level for your code:

```
your.package.level = FINE
```

See the [Tomcat 6](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html)/[Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) logging documentation for more information. The example `logging.properties` file shown there uses `FINE` instead of `DEBUG`:

```
...
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
...
```

and also gives you examples of setting additional logging levels:

```
# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
```

Answer (score 21):

JULI logging levels for Tomcat

**SEVERE** - Serious failures

**WARNING** - Potential problems

**INFO** - Informational messages

**CONFIG** - Static configuration messages

**FINE** - Trace messages

**FINER** - Detailed trace messages

**FINEST** - Highly detailed trace messages

You can find here more
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/pasoe-admin/tomcat-logging.html

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what has already been said (DEBUG -> FINE, FINER, FINEST in JULI), in case you're running Tomcat using an IDE, say Eclipse, note that it stores the configuration on a different path than CATALINA_HOME, so you may need to add

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.31\conf\logging.properties"
```

to explicit set your logging properties.

More on this here: [Where can I view Tomcat log files in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233053/where-can-i-view-tomcat-log-files-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

There is one more thing to try if the other answers here are not solving the problem.

Tomcat provides some components that can be used directly by the application. For example, the [CsrfPreventionFilter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter).

When used within your application and no other special configuration such as a custom log manager, the configuration for this Filter *when inside your application* will be read from `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` and not from the server-wide file in `CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties`.

So if you are not getting DEBUG/TRACE output from a Tomcat component used from within your application, check this file in your application to see if it contains the correct logging configuration.