# Tomcat crashing while deploying the spring application in server:"INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext"

Tags: spring, crash, tomcat6

I am trying to deploy my spring application in a server machine which having the tomcat 6.0.29 server. But tomcat server getting stop automatically while extracting the war.
In **Catalina Log** I have the following:

```
Jan 27, 2012 3:02:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive application.war
```

In **localhost.log**

```
Jan 27, 2012 3:03:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

There is no any stacktrace.

I tried to restart the tomcat but server getting stop while extracting the war file. I tried by increasing the JVM memory to 1024MB. Still same problem.

I have deployed the same war in my another testing server and it is working fine.

Any help...

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in all of the Tomcat logs? Is Tomcat responsive or hangs? Can you make a thread dump using `jstack` or JVisualVM?

Comment: Hai Tomasz Nurkiewicz, Yes I do not have any errors stacktrace in tomcat logs. Tomcat got stopped immediately. And I will try jstack now for thread dump.

Comment: Is it the Tomcat java process which crashes ?

Comment: @nico_ekito, Tomcat getting Crash.

Comment: What version of the JVM are you using ? And which one (Oracle, OpenJDK, Gnu) ?

Comment: @nico_ekito,I am Using Oracle Jdk1.7.0. My main problem is **Facing problem in production server.** Working fine in my local machine and my testing server.

Comment: Try updating the logging level of Spring (DEBUG), and maybe you'll see the bean which crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing something like this "SEVERE: Error listenerStart"? or none in the logs.
If Tomcat fails there should be a thread dump and/or a heap dump in the startup directory.
Also check the ports available from OS/firewall to bind with.

Enabling debug logging might help. (Change the log levels to DEBUG instead of INFO in the log files below)

Enabling Tomcat debug log:
Refer to : [How to set level logging to DEBUG in Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119213/how-to-set-level-logging-to-debug-in-tomcat-6)

Enabling Spring debug log:

You can enable spring debug logging mode (why its failing to deploy the webapp) by adding the `logging.properties`(name should match exactly) in your WEB-INF/classes directory

Refer to : [SEVERE: Error listenerStart](http://blog.dutchworks.nl/2011/03/18/debugging-the-dreaded-severe-error-listenerstart-and-severe-error-filterstart-tomcat-error-messages/)

Comment: Roller and Eric B, Thank you for your information. But the exact problem is, my server Hard disk has some bad blocks. So registry is failing while I am trying to run the big application in tomcat. So I formatted the hard disk and installed all needed tools and tried to deploy the application again. Now it is working fine... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How are you launching Tomcat?  What OS is this?  I have encountered this problem myself in the past when launching Tomcat on CentOS using a startup script.  Usually had something to do with security settings of the files and/or of selinux preventing the writing/reading of certain filespaces on the disk.

Try running from the console using ./catalina.sh run and see if that works on the server (assuming it is a *nix server).  If so, check ownership of all files and read/write permissions.  Disable selinux (if currently enabled) momentarily to see if that makes any difference.

It's a bunch of trial and error when you don't have any further debug information available.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I faced this problem it was due to the fact I was thinking that I am using h2database while the configurations were such that it was using mysql and of course there was no mysql server to connect to. 
I was using a maven project in eclipse and none of my changes were taking effect until I did

Project Properties-> Maven-> Update Project and then in

Servers Tab right click on the server name and Publish.

Check the jdbc.properties file in the webapp (in my case it was somewhere inside /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ folder) not in source code to see what are the final parameters for database connection.