# Supressing warnings on Apache Tomcat stdout

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am running a web-app on apache tomcat that grabs data from the web and then writes into an excel sheet. I am getting several warnings on the tomcat stdout that is making the whole look of the workflow ugly.

How can I suppress the warnings of the apache tomcat stdout?

Comment: Can you post some of your logging examples please.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [How to set level logging to DEBUG in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119213/how-to-set-level-logging-to-debug-in-tomcat-6) or the tomcat documentation on Logging: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

You essentially want to scale the logging down to just (critical) errors.

Dw

Answer (score 1):

Given that Tomcat doesn't write directly to STDOUT, I assume that some library you are using does. You can re-direct this output using the [swallowOutput](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) attribute of the Context.