# how to identify java code where a thread is started when we have thread name in application log

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat6

I am getting below log in my old application , i tried to search with .setName as we set thread name using thread.setName method but not able to see it. i doubt it is started by application and i am searching in all .java files.

```
Jan 30, 2014 1:00:29 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/MyWebApp] appears
to have started a thread named [Control] but has failed to stop it.
This is very likely to create a mem ory leak. Jan 30, 2014 1:00:29 AM
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/MyWebApp] appears to have started a
thread named [MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup] but has
failed to stop it.
```

Not able to understand where these threads( Control and MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager ) are getting started so that i can modify code to stop these threads.

Edit: My Colleague answered one part of it , MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager was [BUG](https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/AXIS2-4898) in Axis2

When i run tomcat in debug mode i see some daemon threads and two other threads (main,Control). Command line arguments for Control thread are showing "org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start". Looks like tomcat is starting this thread, but if this is the case why tomcat will give error log for this?

Comment: Thread name can be set either in `setName` method or using thread constructor see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @SajanChandran I agree with u , but i need to find out way to identify code or class name which is starting that thread

Comment: try scanning through your dependencies and google by `[dependency name] control thread`. That might give you some insight

Comment: @Vipin search for `new Thread(` in your eclipse.

Comment: @SajanChandran no luck using this :(

Comment: @injecteer can you please elaborate which dependency u are talking about. example will be great.

Comment: in your `lib` folder or you `maven` descriptor you must be having some `jar` files or references to them. Those are the libraries your project is using to compile/build/runtime. So, using this list, you can fire up the google search

Comment: Could it be [Spring](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/106615-multithreadedhttpconnectionmanager-s-thread-isn-t-stopped-when-application-shuts-down)? On the forum it says to "call the static method MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdownAll()".

Comment: It is not spring , it is a struts 1.1 application. I am using apache commons lib , axis 1.3 and server is tomcat 6

Comment: Have you tried turning on DEBUG logging for Tomcat and see if it has more info?

Comment: @Sundeep i did not change any setting and i see FINE in logging.properties at several places, what exactly shall i change ?

Comment: @Vipin I am no expert in Tomcat, but usually DEBUG logs provide more information. You should turn on DEBUG logging for the tomcat container. In that file, change FINE to DEBUG and see if you get additional info in logs. See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119213/how-to-set-level-logging-to-debug-in-tomcat-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer and 2 simple solutions to this problem

1. use Kill -QUIT pid to get thread dump and see the stack trace , it
   gives stack trace and tells what exactly the runnable/Thread class
   name is.
2. The other option is to start application in eclipse see get
       information from debug mode. Where we can see what all threads are
       running.

Answer (score 0):

If your thread is run through `ThreadPoolExecutor::runWorker`, you can put a conditional breakpoint there on `task.run()` with the condition `wt.name.equals("my-thread-name")` and step into the code that created the thread.