# FAIL - Deployed application at context path /RxCircle but context failed to start

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans-7

FAIL - Deployed application at context path /RxCircle but context failed to start
The module has not been deployed.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:173)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:125)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:202)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

i am using tomcat 6
netbeans 7.0
java 6

i am getting this error when i am running my application in netbeans..

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that either (1) Your web.xml is missing, (2) your applicationContext is malformed or (3) your versions are not playing nicely together.

Since you are using Netbeans you can view the Server Log by doing this:

1. Open the `Services` window (if it is not open go to: `Window > Services`)
2. Right-click on the `Tomcat` Server and select `View Server Log`.

Now you can see the actual exception that is causing Tomcat not to deploy your war.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic error message and can be due to any reason like wrong servlet filter defined or malformed application context file.
To understand fully you need to get more logging details from tomcat.
So set the logging level to debug in tomcat and then start the tomcat.
Below url you may refer for further details

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

[How to set level logging to DEBUG in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119213/how-to-set-level-logging-to-debug-in-tomcat-6)

Hopefully you will get more details about the deployment error root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the Tomcat server so as to allow Netbeans to run it. If the server is already running when Netbeans tries to deploy an app Netbeans will display the delopy failed message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using Java 8, Tomcat 8, NetBeans 8.1.

What I did was, I manually replaced:
1. nbproject/build-impl.xml 
2. web/WEB-INF/web.xml

with a previous version of the files. Please make sure to have backups.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue
I searched lot of solutions but not worked
If you are facing the same problem then the solution is

First you have backup your web.xml  code file from your
project NetBeanss
Now delete web.xml from project
Now right click on web-inf file chose web after that chose deployment descriptor
After that
Now you can  run your prj check your solution is solve as context will run on localhost server
Afte thaer will some error because we can't save our servlet file link so do it

Run it

Now you will see your problem solve

It's worked for.me