# log4j console warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I am getting two console warnings:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.roussev.selenium4j.MainTestCase).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Following is my log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <appender name="appender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="selenium4j.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value ="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="appender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I am not sure why am I getting this error. The xml seems to be fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common reason for this undescriptive message is ::

The log4j.xml is not properly added in your classpath.

See more here ::: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6616858/1085285

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but thats the solution is for log4j properties file...I dont know what is log4j.xml equivalent of those lines.

Comment: had you put your xml in /WEB-INF/classes.