# Log4j, Spring MVC, No appenders could be found for logger

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

The log4j is working fine, however, at server startup, I am getting these warnings:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

It's implying the `log4j.properties` could not be found.  But I am not sure how to fix that because everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly

Comment: I have placed log4j.properties in classpath and the logging is working as configured. But, am not sure how to get rid of the message on server startup.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 17):

Place the spring Log4jConfigListener as the first listener in your web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You set upp the location of the log4j properties in a context-param but you do not need to do this if it is placed on the classpath.

An example is ..

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 6):

Move these 2 lines of code to the top of your web.xml to resolve the problem.

```
<!-- location of log4j config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- applies log4j configuration -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse and tomcat for your development, following method should work

Declare the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Create log4j.properties file and put it in the resources folder ("src/main/resources")

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/mylogfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

And then in your class, instantiate logger

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WelcomeController.class);
```

after that you can use logger any where you want

```
logger.debug("this will appear as a log in mylogfile.log!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had configured `<filter>` in my `web.xml` file which was creating problem. I commented that out, and then it worked for me!