# Facing a issue in Log4J

Tags: log4j

I am just begining in Log4J an I am facing an issue that I don't realy understand.
I am using Eclipse IDE, and after compilation the got this message:

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at test.log.Program.main(Program.java:20)***

See below the code I wrote

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Program.class);
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{                      
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[0]);
    logger.info("Hello PropertyConfigurator");
}
```

Please advise.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't related to Log4j. You are probably calling your program without an argument, which means that args[0] isn't defined. Try this:

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Program.class);
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  if (args.length > 0){ 
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[0]);
  }
  logger.info("Hello PropertyConfigurator");
}
```

Now it should work regardless of the presence of a parameter.

Comment: Hi, it is me again. I edit my code like in your answer, but now I have the following error:log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (test.log.Program).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: @user893953 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly