# log4j not printing anything in groovy on ubuntu

Tags: groovy, log4j

I'm trying to get a Hello World app working with groovy/log4j/ubuntu (working with Groovy 1.7.10). By default, I get no output to the console:

- Created ~/.groovy/lib, and downloaded the latest log4j jar into there.
- Created a.groovy:

cat a.groovy:

```
#! /usr/bin/groovy
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
def log = Logger.getLogger(getClass())

println "Log starting"
log.info("This is Info")
log.error("This is error")
println "Log finished"
```

Gave it permissions and ran it, and got:

```
Log starting
Log finished
```

Shouldn't the default config created a console appender and output to console?

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228151/11236), I tried adding a call to `org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();`, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: i think that getClass() is a bit weird here... you are writing a one-off script that isn't really a class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the Level so that it displays `INFO` messages...

Try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/groovy

// Grab Log4j
@Grab( 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16' )
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

def log = Logger.getLogger( getClass() )

Logger.rootLogger.level = Level.INFO

println "Log starting"
log.info "This is Info"
log.error "This is error"
println "Log finished"
```

There's a [blog post here](http://robertmaldon.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/programmatically-configuring-log4j-and.html) I found that shows programatically setting up Log4j

Or, as [sreejith says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10683682/6509), add a log4j properties file to your classpath (or load it in)

To change the default root appender, you can do:

```
@Grab( 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16' )
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
def log = Logger.getLogger(getClass())

Logger.rootLogger.with {
  level = Level.INFO
  removeAllAppenders()
  addAppender( new ConsoleAppender( new PatternLayout( '%d %-5p [%t]: %m%n' ) ) )
}

println "Log starting"
log.info "This is Info"
log.error "This is error"
println "Log finished"
```

To print:

```
2012-05-21 11:48:48,225 INFO  [Thread-29]: This is Info
```

The different pattern symbols [can be found here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)

Comment: While're we at it, do you have a quick snippet on how to configure the console appender's conversion pattern to include the date/time?

Comment: @ripper234 added that info to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a  file with the following contents

log4j.rootCategory=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %40.40c:%4L - %m%n

and add it to the classpath of the project.