# Log4J warning: Initialize log4j system

Tags: logging, log4j

I am learning log4j. But, I get this error not sure if I'm missing something. I have all the jars in place.

```
public class LoggingDemo {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingDemo.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Starting App....");
        System.out.println("Testing log4j.......");
        logger.info("Terminating App!");
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this all the time when I am creating a new project.  You need to create a log4j.properties file and add it to your class path.  See the Configuration section of the manual http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Or just change your code to:

```
public class LoggingDemo {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingDemo.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        logger.info("Starting App....");
        System.out.println("Testing log4j.......");
        logger.info("Terminating App!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention! I figured that was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing a log4j.properties file. Someone who has the same issue should make a log4j.properties file in the src folder with the contents given below.

**Output to the Console**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When an error appears like please initialize the log4j that means "log4j.properties" file is unavailable in the project class path.

You need to create a log4j.properties file and add it to your class path.

Or You can pass the JVM argument as shown below

-Dlog4j.configuration=file:.\log4j.properties

So JVM will initilize the log4j from the specified property.

In the log4j file you can specify the following things

## root logger configuration. WARN, It is the log4j level and ConsoleAppender is appender which prints the out to the console.

log4j.rootLogger=WARN, ConsoleAppender

It seems issue is duplicate of [How to initialize log4j properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly?s=2|2.9929)