# How to specify log file location in log4j.properties file While running jar file from command prompt

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am having jar file which i am running from command prompt using java -jar. I am using log statements inside my jar file classes. can you tell how to configure the location to place log file in log4j.prperties file.

Note : I am running the jar file in remote machine

Comment: The file should reside in the classpath. So either in the JAR itself or in some other directory which is part of the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

log4j properties/xml  file can be configured in multiple ways. You can check this 
[How to initialize log4j properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly)