# When IBM WAS starts it gives log4j : WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

Tags: log4j, websphere

I am using IBM WAS as my server for my application.I have given log4j.properties in classpath of IBM WAS.It works fine.I want to change the name of log4j.properties to something like abclog4j.properties.My application is Eclipse based.
If I change it and start my server it gives me log4j : WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly error
How can I change it's name?

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1140358/1311351

Answer (score 1):

According to this page: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

*The preferred way to specify the default initialization file is through the **log4j.configuration** system property. In case the system property **log4j.configuration** is not defined, then set the string variable resource to its default value "log4j.properties".*

So if you set the **log4j.configuration** system property before log4j is dynamically loaded (i.e., referenced in any object), then log4j will use that value for the name of the config file.

```
   System.setProperty("log4j.configuration","abclog4j.properties");
```

You could do this in a static block at the beginning of some base class so that it is set before any log4j references are encountered.