# How to get Log4j to use stdout?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm currently using log4j in some code I'm working on for debugging purposes. I've been running my code with `java -jar test.jar | tee file.txt` to log to a file but now I want to be able to switch the file I'm logging to while it's still running, something that `tee` can't do. Right now I'm doing this

```java
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

public void main() {
File file = new File(/path/to/file);
System.setOut(new PrintStream(file));
System.out.println("hello world"); //This works.
log.info("hello world"); //this doesn't.
```

For some reason the Logger output isn't going to my file, it's going to my console, but `println()` works fine. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix this?

Thanks.

Edit: Here's my log4j.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!--<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" />-->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c:%L] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.company">
        <level value="trace" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.company.Selenium">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>    
    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="warn" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Also I'm getting the following error when I run my project

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: ConsoleAppender should help u

Comment: First you need to post your log4j properties

Comment: I don't have a log4j.properties in my eclipse project, but I posted my log4j.xml.

Comment: Are you getting any Log4J errors that indicate that it has not been properly initialized; such as:

    `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger`

Comment: Check out this [posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly). It should help you figure out your problem.

Comment: I used one of those solutions. The errors went away but it's still not logging to my file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example taken from this link [Using Log4j for debugging in Java](https://www.stackstalk.com/2014/02/using-log4j-for-debugging-in-java.html). You might be missing BasicConfigurator.configure();

```
public class Log4jTest {
  // Initialize logger for instance Log4jTest
  static Logger log  = Logger.getLogger(Log4jTest.class);

  public static void main (String[] args) {
     // Basic configurator to log debug messages to the console
     BasicConfigurator.configure();         
      
     // Add some log messages
     log.debug("This is a debug message");
     log.trace("This is a trace message");         
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. BasicConfigurator.configure() worked for me. Something to note, you need to make sure BasicConfiugrater.configure() comes AFTER you call System.setOut(), otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Fixed the broken link above.

Answer (score 8):

please add this into your log4j.properties file

```
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` must be in the default package. e.g.:

[image: Default package]

Of if you are using Maven, in "src/main/resources":

[image: resources]