# Exclude resources from a dependent jar with Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, resources, log4j

I have a third party jar file that I have to use, but unfortunately it contains an embedded log4j configuration file as a resource. When I include the third party jar as a Maven dependency, I also pick up their log4j configuration, which overrides my own.

Is there a way to tell Maven to include a jar dependency, while excluding a specific resource within that jar?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *NO*

But, if you wish to use your own log4j configuration set the System Property named `log4j.configuration`  using `-Dlog4j.configuration=somefile.properties` or similar.

See this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `maven` [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) for that. You can use filters to exclude the resource.

A working example of how to achieve this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>logback.xml</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken. This excludes a dependency, not a resource in Project-A which was what the OP asked for?