# Exception while executing java class

Tags: java, maven

I executed this command

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=crawler.Crawler
```

and found this

> An exception occured while executing the Java class. org/apache/log4j/Logger

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" si:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>clojars.org</id>
    <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
     <id>twitter4j.org</id>
     <name>twitter4j.org Repository</name>
     <url>http://twitter4j.org/maven2</url>
     <releases>
     <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
     </snapshots>
   </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
```

second part

```
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.6</source>
           <target>1.6</target>
       </configuration>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

Error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Comment: Presumably log4j is in 'test' scope, not 'compile' scope.

Comment: There clearly is a problem with your dependencies. Log4J is missing from the classpath. Are you sure you setup the `<scope>` correctly?

Comment: Execuse me i'm new in java and maven how can i check <scope> and where can i find it ?

Comment: Is there a pom.xml you can show us?

Comment: What even is the error?

Comment: Thanks for replying, i post pom file in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add dependency on log4j

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml file (after dependency on junit).

You can read about this dependency in maven repo:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17

Comment: I got this after appending <dependency>log4j. please initialize log4j system properly

Comment: I am glad, my answer helped you. And now you have new challenge. I think, this topic help you: [How to initialize log4j properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly) I guess, we can close this discussion. I voted up your question. You can voteup and accept my answer. Good luck!