# How to initialize the log4j system properly

Tags: java, log4j

I'm getting two warnings.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.org.Resolver).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

How to resolve it?

My java class name **Resolver.java**

In java class i'm calling

```
private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Resolver.class);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize log4j properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly)

Comment: You should write log4j.properties file, [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put log4j.properties or log4j.xml in your classpath. So, create file name log4j.properties and replace the content with below:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#. represents the current folder (usually the project root folder)        
log4j.appender.file.File=./logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```