# I am writting code in eclipse juno but while executing it.it is showing following error

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have written code in Eclipse Juno, but my webapp is not working when I view it in the browser. The browser opens, but after that there is no action.

Eclipse's console isn't showing any errors, but after adding the Apache Poi jar file, it is showing following error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Currently, I am using Mozila Firefox 33.0.1. I tried to run the code with different Selenium jars like 2.44, 2.45 and 2.46.

Comment: For the warning, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1140358/646543 -- in particular, the top two answers. However, it is currently impossible to tell what other problems there might be, given that we cannot see your code. You may want to review the help center for info on [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your logger is not configured properly. You should fix it, and then you may get some useful information about what is wrong with your app.