# Spark doc build process hangs on Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: apache-spark, slf4j

I followed this

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/README.md

to build spark docs,but it hangs on:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

after half an hour,no further info got printed out.I tried to add slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar into spark/lib_managed/jars,then rerun

```
jekyll build
```

still hang on these messages,how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was adding Logback Classic Module to the classpath:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.7
and removing any other implementations of `StaticLoggerBinder`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an explanation in the **Spark** documentation:

http://sparkjava.com/documentation#how-do-i-enable-logging

> You might have seen this message when starting **Spark**:
>
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details.Copy
>
> To enable logging, just add the following dependency to your project:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>     <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
>     <version>1.7.21</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

For **Gradle**, check this thread for more details:
[How to set SLF4J in IntelliJ with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178076/how-to-set-slf4j-in-intellij-with-gradle#answers-header)

Then you'll might need to configure slf4j properly, by creating a config file, but that's a different topic. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_configuration.htm#:%7E:text=properties%20file%20is%20a%20log4j,logger%20is%20defined%20as%20DEBUG.) if that's the case.