# When running test cases with maven, logger not generating log file

Tags: maven, log4j

Getting below error when run the batch file.

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (devpinoyLogger).
>
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize log4j properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly)

Comment: Not duplicated post, it is something different for maven

Comment: Then please provide details. Is there a log4j.properties or log4j.xml file in maven resources folder? what's its content?

Comment: I am using log4j.properties, and file is places in src folder

Comment: it should be placed under src/main/resources then, move it there and the issue will be most likely solved

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to fix this is to add a `log4j.properties` file in `main/src/test/resources`.

Here's a sample `log4j.properties` file that will output logs to the console:

```
# Set root logger level to INFO and its only appender to stdout.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Define the stdout appender to output logs to the console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```