# how to set logging in groovy project (logs from all classes) to a single file

Tags: logging, groovy, log4j

I'm able to set logging in a single groovy class. But I want to send all the logs from different groovy classes to a single file. Is it possible ? Please find below my log code in my groovy class.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.apache.log4j.*
import groovy.util.logging.*

@Log4j
public class TibcoAppConfGenertor {

    public TibcoAppConfGenertor() {

        log.level = Level.DEBUG
        log.addAppender(new FileAppender(new TTCCLayout(), 'Tibco.log'));
        log.addAppender(new FileAppender(new TTCCLayout(), 'Tibco_Exception.log'));
        //log.info 'Simple sample to show log field is injected.'

    }




    public void generateServiceXML() {
        log.info 'generateServiceXML'

        getApplicationGroups();

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize log4j properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Groovy runs above Java you can use one of the Java Libraries.
Personally I would prefer using slf4j than using log4j. The difference from log4j is explained [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108683/slf4j-vs-log4j-which-one-to-prefer).
If you are using Grails MVC framework than it would be a good practice to make a Service which handles all your logs.

Example for such a Service can be something like that:

```
public class LoggerService {

private static Logger defaultLogger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerService.class);

// Add more methods here 

}
```

Every class uses the logger should state the following line:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger('className')
```

The 'className' of course should be replaced with the relevant class you uses.