# How to read log4j 2 configuration programmatically?

Tags: java, log4j

I'm working with a third-party **log4j v2** [Appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) which gives me the opportunity to plug-in some custom classes of my own (the Appender will create those via Reflection).

In other words: My class gets instantiated from the Appender which again gets instantiated as part of log4j's normal bootstrap. I do not have control over the Appender which is from another library.

I would like a few properties for my own custom class to be read from the Log4j configuration. It makes sense that it lives there since it is indeed related to logging.

However, I cannot figure out how to do this. At the moment I do something like this from the constructor of my custom class:

```java
LoggerContext loggerContext = LoggerContext.getContext(true);
if (loggerContext != null) {
    Configuration config = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
    if (config != null) {
        StrSubstitutor strSubstitutor = config.getStrSubstitutor();
        if (strSubstitutor != null) {
            StrLookup variableResolver = strSubstitutor.getVariableResolver();
            if (variableResolver != null) {
                String myVar = variableResolver.lookup("myPropertyName");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the problem seems to be that at this point in time (*during* bootstrap) the Log4j configuration is indeed not yet initialized so

```
LoggerContext.getContext(true).getConfiguration()
```

returns an instance of `DefaultConfiguration` (which obviously doesn't have my property) where
I would have expected an instance of `XmlConfiguration`. The latter I get when I call `LoggerContext.getContext(true).getConfiguration()` at any *later* point in time and I can indeed read my custom properties from that one.

Comment: Do you have some knowledge on how your classes are instantiated? Is it a simple `Class.forName` or maybe it does some property injection using [plugin attribute annotations](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/package-summary.html) or similar?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz. My class is initiated via simple `Class.forName`. Although it is a third-party Appender, I do in fact have visibility into the [source code of the Appender](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-library-javalogging/blob/main/src/main/java/com/splunk/logging/HttpEventCollectorLog4jAppender.java#L98).

Comment: It may give a good start. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you guessed, and as stated in the [Log4j architecture documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html) when they describe `LoggerContext` `Configuration`:

> Every `LoggerContext` has an active `Configuration`. The `Configuration` contains all the `Appender`s, context-wide `Filter`s, `LoggerConfig`s and contains the reference to the `StrSubstitutor`. During reconfiguration two `Configuration` objects will exist. Once all `Logger`s have been redirected to the new `Configuration`, the old `Configuration` will be stopped and discarded.

This reconfiguration process is performed in the `LoggerContext` [`start` method](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/5edf43758f104affad9842753e66be173fc4d68a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.java#L256-L278), which in turn calls [`reconfigure`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/5edf43758f104affad9842753e66be173fc4d68a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.java#L679-L700), and finally [`setConfiguration`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/5edf43758f104affad9842753e66be173fc4d68a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.java#L598-L641).

Pay attention to the following line in `setConfiguration`:

```java
firePropertyChangeEvent(new PropertyChangeEvent(this, PROPERTY_CONFIG, prev, config));
```

As you can see, `LoggerContext` will propagate the change in the configuration to the configured `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`s.

This approach is followed in the own library in the [`Log4jBridgeHandler` class](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/20f9a97dbe5928c3b5077bcdd2a22ac92e941655/log4j-jul/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/jul/Log4jBridgeHandler.java). In its `init` method you can see:

```java
if (propagateLevels) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")    // no need to close the AutoCloseable ctx here
    LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
    context.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    propagateLogLevels(context.getConfiguration());
    // note: java.util.logging.LogManager.addPropertyChangeListener() could also
    // be set here, but a call of JUL.readConfiguration() will be done on purpose
}
```

And they define the appropriate `propertyChange` event handler:

```java
@Override
// impl. for PropertyChangeListener
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    SLOGGER.debug("Log4jBridgeHandler.propertyChange(): {}", evt);
    if (LoggerContext.PROPERTY_CONFIG.equals(evt.getPropertyName())  &&  evt.getNewValue() instanceof Configuration) {
        propagateLogLevels((Configuration) evt.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

I think you can follow a similar approach in your component. Please:

1. Make it implement `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`.
2. In the corresponding `propertyChange` event handler method, reconfigure your component as required:

```java
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    if (LoggerContext.PROPERTY_CONFIG.equals(evt.getPropertyName())  &&  evt.getNewValue() instanceof Configuration) {
        Configuration config = (Configuration) evt.getNewValue();
        if (config != null) {
            StrSubstitutor strSubstitutor = config.getStrSubstitutor();
            if (strSubstitutor != null) {
                StrLookup variableResolver = strSubstitutor.getVariableResolver();
                if (variableResolver != null) {
                    String myVar = variableResolver.lookup("myPropertyName");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. In its constructor or initialization code, register your component as a listener for the reconfiguration event:

```java
LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
context.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, so Log4j fires a `propertyChange` event when it *finishes* the configuration. I'm guessing your proposal can work but it means that my class' config properties (those I wish to read from Log4j config) cannot be final. In other words: my class cannot be said to be fully initialized until it has received the event. Let me work on that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are welcome @peterh. Yes, you are right: a you can see in the library source code, the property change event will be raised when it finishes the configuration. As a consequence, you should consider your component configuration transient until your property change handler is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you **do** have access to the third-party appender, I would modify it to take advantage of Log4j2 injection capabilities. For example you can:

1. Inject a `Node` into the appender's `@PluginFactory`:

   ```java
   @PluginFactory
   public static HttpEventCollectorLog4jAppender createAppender(
         ...
         @PluginAttribute("middleware") final String middlewareClassName,
         @PluginAttribute("eventBodySerializer") final String eventBodySerializerClassName,
         @PluginAttribute("eventHeaderSerializer") final String eventHeaderSerializerClassName,
         ...
         @PluginNode Node node)
   ```
2. Use the `Node` to retrieve plugins of the correct type:

   ```java
      HttpSenderMiddleware middleware = null;
      EventBodySerializer eventBodySerializer = null;
      EventHeaderSerializer eventHeaderSerializer = null;
      for (final Node child : node.getChildren()) {
         final PluginType< ? > pluginType = child.getType();
         final Object component = child.getObject();
         switch (pluginType.getElementName()) {
            case "middleware" :
               middleware = (HttpSenderMiddleware) component;
               break;
            case "eventBodySerializer" :
               eventBodySerializer = (EventBodySerializer) component;
               break;
            case "eventHeaderSerializer" :
               eventHeaderSerializer = (EventHeaderSerializer) component;
         }
      }
      if (middlewareClass != null && !middlewareClass.isEmpty()) {
         try {
            middleware = (HttpEventCollectorMiddleware.HttpSenderMiddleware) (Class.forName(middlewareClass).newInstance());
         } catch (Exception ignored) {
         }
      }
     ...
   ```
3. Adapt the `HttpEventCollectorLog4jAppender`'s constructor to take class instances instead of class names as parameters.
4. Annotate your classes as Log4j plugins:

```java
   @Plugin(name = "MyMiddleware", elementType = "middleware", category = "Core")
   public class Middleware extends HttpSenderMiddleware {

       @PluginFactory
       public static Middleware createMiddleware(
           @PluginAttribute("one") String one,
           @PluginAttribute("two") String two
       ) {
       ...
       }
```

5. Use them in your configuration:

```xml
<SplunkHttp>
    <MyMiddleware one="1" two="2" />
</SplunkHttp>
```

Comment: I said I had "visibility" into the Appender, nothing more.  This solution presented here is not a short-term solution as it means sending a PR to that third-party project and hoping they'll accept it. Nevertheless I see it as the most correct solution ....if only I had control over that source.

Comment: Since the library is under an Apache licence it is probably better to use a fork of the library until the PR is accepted. I [forked the project](https://github.com/ppkarwasz/splunk-library-javalogging) and committed the suggestions in this answer. When I'll have time to write a couple of unit test, I'll send a PR.

Comment: I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-library-javalogging/pull/196).

Comment: Thanks. Still believe this is formally the correct approach but short-term I'll have to go with [jccampanero's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68899863/1504556). Your proposal deserves all the upvotes it can get.