# How to implement dynamic referenced configuration in Java?

Tags: java, configuration, yaml

I have a configuration (`config.properties`) something like

```
app.rootDir=
app.reportDir=${app.rootDir}/report
```

The `app.rootDir` is not a fixed parameter and it must be initialized by external module. I need keep the `${app.reportDir}` keep dynamic reference to `${app.rootDir}`. 
Use pseudo code to illustrate the problem:

```
// Init the root dir as '/usr/app'
config.setValue('app.rootDir','/usr/app');

// I need the reportDir to be '/usr/app/report'
String reportDir = config.getValue('app.reportDir');
```

I can write some codes to get this feature but I'd like to know if there is any existing library do this?

I can use properties, yaml, or json as configuration file type, according to the library availability.

Comment: You can use Apache Configuration or Commons Config

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412132/can-i-reference-another-property-in-a-properties-file-use-property

Comment: Thanks ,commons config works perfectly