# How to use Apache Commons PropertiesConfiguration as MessageSource in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, spring-4, apache-commons-config

I currently use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` from Spring as `MessageSource` in order to read internationalization messages.

The version of Spring I use is: *4.3.1.RELEASE*

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:messages/messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="1" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

The thing is that I want to use [PropertiesConfiguration (from Apache Commons Configuration 2)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfiguration.html) as a `MessageSource`. The problem I have is that both extend different classes. I would need to know if Apache Commons Configuration provides a ready-made `MessageSource` with `PropertiesConfiguration` or how to make a new `MessageSource` with this configuration.

The advantage of using this configuration is to have [Variable Interpolation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation) that is unavailable in Java's [Properties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

My question is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412132/can-i-reference-another-property-in-a-properties-file-use-property), but with a twist because I don't use properties directly in my app, but through a message source provided by Spring and I don't want to change that code.

Comment: That interpolation is also provided by the `MessageSource`. And the `MessageSource` is for messages/translations not for properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum Are you sure? I must be doing it wrong then. Could you provide me an example or a link? I tried to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties and failed.

Comment: It depends on what you want. As stated a `MessageSource` is for messages (i.e. I18N ) not for configuring your application for that you should use a `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`.