# Duplicate property value

Tags: java, properties

Is it possible to duplicate the value (without having to copy and paste) of a property?  Is there anyway to mark it such that I could reuse the value of foo for the property baz?

```
foo=bar
baz=bar
```

We have common pieces of information which can appear on many pages.  It'd be nice to be able to create one property with the common information, and then use this value in another property to help us keep DRY.

Comment: Are the values always immutable (such as Strings, wrappers, etc)?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/java-properties-file-how-to-reference-already-defined-property-later-dir-defau

Comment: Question is not clear.. can you please elaborate more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly - no. If you pass the properties through a post-processor - yes. For example spring's `<context:property-placeholder-configurer />` parses `${placeholder}` syntax and replaces it with the proper value.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Looks like I'll need to extend out the velocity tool which pulls these out in our UI.