# Reference other variables in Java properties file

Tags: java, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference another property in java.util.Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties)

I want to refer to other variables in my properties file, e.g.:

```
name=World
text=Hello $(name)!
```

"text" should now be "Hello World!".

I know I could do it by hand but is there anything I could use which does the work for me?

Comment: And what should happen, if at a later point, the property `name` is changed to "grils and guys"? Will `text`remain "Hello World!" or will it become "Hello Gils and guys!"?

Comment: doesn't really matter for me. so remaining "Hello World!" would be fine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options mentioned in the question that [Michael linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/872272/922954) in his comment above that I feel may help you is [eproperties](http://code.google.com/p/eproperties/). Looks pretty promising.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

Doing it by hand is the normal way to go. But I suppose you could also override the `put` method of `Properties` so that it's done only once.

```
@Override
public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
    super.put(key, substitute(value))
}

/** Substitutes variables with their value */
private String substitue(String string) {
   // TODO: find "{...}" and replace it by the value obtained by get()
   // Be careful here!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the building blogs from the properties file and then programatically construct what you need in java.

Comment: @jhasse knows he could do it by hand...