# using properties within the properties file

Tags: java, properties

I apologize for the title.. i couldn't find a better way to explain the situation.

I use to load properties file using a Property class as described in the URL http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/Props.html

my question is can I use properties within that properties file ?

example:

test.properties

```
 url.main="http://mysite.com"
    url.games={url.main}/games
    url.images={url.main}/images
    .
    .
    .
```

is that possible with some other syntax?

thanks

Comment: Other suggestions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/java-properties-file-how-to-reference-already-defined-property-later-dir-defa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never seen that before. You *could* make your own preprocessor of course. As long as the referenced property occurs before any references to it, you should be able to implement it using some regular expressions/string replacement. But: I *would not recommend* this method.

Better resolve the duplication by defining different properties:

1. change: `url.games={url.main}/games` into `url.games_extension=/games`
2. prepend: `url.main` to `url.games_extension` to get the full games url in your application code.

Answer (score 7):

Apache Commons Configuration provides for this: http://commons.apache.org/configuration/

Simple example code for loading the configuration file:

```
Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("config.properties");
```

You can have 'variable interpolated' properties, as described here http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation

```
application.name = Killer App
application.version = 1.6.2

application.title = ${application.name} ${application.version}
```

And it also allows you to include other configuration files while you're at it:

```
include = colors.properties
include = sizes.properties
```

Besides a whole range of other features.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own Configuration library that supports variable expansion in properties files, [have a look](https://github.com/lviggiano/owner#variables-expansion) and see if it provides what you need. An article I wrote to introduce the feature is [here](http://en.newinstance.it/2013/02/04/owner-1-0-3-whats-new-part-1-variable-expansion/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to substitute the property value within the property file/object but you may replace property value once you read via `getProperty()` method. To produce concatenated messages  - have a look at [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class.

```
String baseValue=prop.getProperty("url.main");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this and it isn't that difficult, you simply subclass the Properties class and implement your own **getProperty** method, check for a pattern and replace it if necessary.

```
//this makes the pattern ${sometext}
static public final String JAVA_CONFIG_VARIABLE = "\\$\\{(.*)\\}";

@Override
public String getProperty(String key)
{
    String val = super.getProperty(key);
    if( val != null && val.indexOf("${") != -1 )
    {
        //we have at least one replacable parm, let's replace it
        val = replaceParms(val);
    }
    return val;
 }

 public final String replaceParms(String in)
 {
     if(in == null) return null;
     //this could be precompiled as Pattern is supposed to be thread safe
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(JAVA_CONFIG_VARIABLE);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(in);
     StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
     while (matcher.find())
     {
         String replaceStr = matcher.group(1);
         String prop = getProperty(replaceStr);   
         //if it isn't in our properties file, check if it is a system property
         if (prop == null )
             prop = System.getProperty(replaceStr);
         if( prop == null )
         {
            System.out.printf("Failed to find property '%s' for '%s'\n", replaceStr, in);
         }
         else
         {
           matcher.appendReplacement(buf, prop);
         } 
     }
     matcher.appendTail(buf);
     String result = buf.toString();
     return result;
 }
```