# Replace placeholder within property file

Tags: java, interpolation, properties-file

I have a properties file in JAVA as follows:

```
base_url = test/url

api_url = ${base_url}/api/url
```

Now, whenever I try to read property "api_url", I get the value as:
"**${base_url}/api/url"**,
but what I am looking for is to get "**test/url/api/url**".

I am using Environment class to read the property file.
I using spring 4 with java based configurations.

Note: I tried looking for a solution, but only relevant link I found was 
[using properties within the properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869482/using-properties-within-the-properties-file),
and I am not really looking for the work-around suggesting in the solution.

Comment: put the code where you read the properties. and full package for the `Environment` class

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring 4, you can try PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, that should resolve the nested properties

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the properties like this

```
@Value("${base_url}") private String baseUrl;
@Value("${api_url}") private String apiUrl;
```