# Can One property value be assigned to another property in other properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties

I have two `.properties` files in which i have same value for two properties each file. So I thought to refer one value to other as for example:

1.config.properties

```
 path= /opt/logs/bundle
```

2.default.properties

`default =/opt/logs/bundle` (same as path in config.properties)

Now here as default property value is same as path so i thought to give like:

```
default = {path}
```

but here i am not able to get that path. Can anyone please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Java? Or some other technology? Please add a suitable language/tech tag

Comment: Which technology u r talking about?

Comment: i am using java, spring..

Answer (score 1):

In my project, EncryptablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer has been used and then 'Resource [] locations' property of its parent 'PropertiesLoaderSupport' has been assigned each of the properties file that I want to load. I guess this is the reason I don't face any error.

For Example:

```
<bean id="frameworkPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="stringEncryptor" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <bean parent="frameworkConfigResourceFactoryBean">
                <property name="resourceName" value="framework-config.properties" />
            </bean>
            <bean ................> </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And in database-config.properties:

```
 database.driver.class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 database.connection.url=${database.connection.url}
 database.username=root
 database.password=${database.password}
```

Also in filter.properties:

```
 database.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MySQLDBName?rewriteBatchedStatements=true
 database.password=root
```

Answer (score 0):

the `Properties` class in java does not have a functionality to *reference* other properties. If you have ever seen a `.properties` file, that uses references, the application that interprets that `.properties` file adds this functionality on top of the `Properties` class. E.g. you have to look up the property path yourself, if you find a value that begins with `{` and ends with `}`.

On the other hand, when using a specific configuration file format (like spring's bean.xml) of a certain library, that library may have added references inside their format. It is quite possible, that you can find a library that adds references on top of java's `Properties` facility or that `Spring` has something in it's huge pack of "whatever you need" already.

Comment: do you know any of such library which stands on top of properties which supports such references.

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties, eproperties is the name of the library that is mentioned...

Comment: i want to add dependency but not jar..do you know how to do it..if so please let me know