# Is it possible to one variable points to other in java properties file?

Tags: java, properties

I have a lot of rows/entry in my properties file. Rows are grouped in categories to keep file easier to maintain. I have two key which have the same value. I don't want to remove one because it makes my file harder to maintain.

```
#category1
var1=foo
....
#category2
var2=foo
```

Is there any way to make var1 points to var2? I think about sth like that:

```
    #category1
    var1=->var2 #point to var2
    ....
    #category2
    var2=foo
```

Comment: No it is not possible to do that.

Comment: But you can support values-as-keys in your own code.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties

Comment: Did you try var2 = {var1} ?

Comment: @superEb Support values-as-keys in my code is difficult becouse I use org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource which uses properties file.

Comment: @nachokk I tried but it did not work.

Comment: You could, but you'd have to interpret and expand he values yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) implements the [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface so you can do everything that this interface offers with it. To allow value to represent a reference to an other key you could wrap the code for getting the value in such a ways that it check whether the value is actually key and then return the value that is mapped by that key.

so you could implement something like this:

```
String value1 = p.getProperty("var1");
while(p.containsKey(value1)) {
    value1 = p.getProperty(value1);
}
```

better: add a prefix - `$` for example - to value to identify a reference, only if present then resolve:

```
String value1 = p.getProperty("var1");
while(value1.startsWith("$")) {
    value1 = p.getProperty(value1.substring(1));
}
```

A good way for wrapping the retrieve-code is by extending the `Properties` class and override the method `getProperty`.

For `org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` you could extend it, override which ever methods you want and configure spring to inject your version of the class.

Comment: I wanted a quick way to facilitate my task. Your way is not quick becasue of the need to extend ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource. I do not like to shoot out of a cannon to fly. But your answer is correct so I accepted it. Thanks.