# Properties File Variable Concatenation

Tags: properties

I have a properties file where I'd like to define a file path as a variable and then reference it.  This is causing a file not found exception:

```
test.folder=C:/code/
file={test.folder}File.csv
```

But this works:

```
file=C:/code/File.csv
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: variable substitution does not work in standard property files. You must implement this yourself or find a library doing this for you. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties

Answer (score 12):

This should works:

```
test.folder=C:/code/

file=${test.folder}File.csv
```

Answer (score 5):

In properties file i didn't think that you can concatenate the variable but you can do something like the following:

config.properties

> ```
> test.folder=C:/code/
> file=File.csv
> ```

Then in your java code concatenate two variable:

```
filePath = folder + file;
```

and if you are using spring xml file you can use:

```
<property name="filePath" value=${test.folder}${file} />
```