# In Java Properties, can you put property substitutions in other property key names?

Tags: java, properties

In Java Properties, can you use property substitutions in the property ***keys*** of the other property key names?

Something like this:

```
between=Between
and=and
greater.than=Greaterthan
${between}1${and}4Units=1-4
${between}5${and}8Units=5-8
${between}9${and}20Units=9-20
${between}21${and}50Units=21-50
${between}51${and}99Units=51-99
${greater.than}100Units=100-999
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Commons Configuration supports property substitution (or properties referencing another property) through **values**. There is no current support for substituting **key names** in properties. However, the least you can do is to extend the implementation by creating a custom property reader to achieve what you're trying to do.

Read on the ff. references:

- [HowTo](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide_v1.10/howto_properties.html#Properties_files)
- [API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfiguration.html)