# Downloading local error message ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Spring Boot. I have a service where the parameter is validated

```
@Override
public void registerUser(
        @Valid RegisterDTO registerDTO
) {
```

The field that is validated is e. g.

```
@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,36}")
private String username;
```

Then I set ExceptionHandler to pick up this exception

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ValidationErrorDTO processValidationError(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
    ValidationErrorDTO validationErrorDTO = new ValidationErrorDTO();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> set =  ex.getConstraintViolations();

    for (Iterator<ConstraintViolation<?>> iterator = set.iterator();iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        ConstraintViolation<?> next =  iterator.next();

        validationErrorDTO.getFieldErrors()
                .add(new ErrorFieldDTO(((PathImpl)next.getPropertyPath()).getLeafNode().getName(),
                        next.getMessage()));
    }

    return validationErrorDTO;
}
```

I have a validationMessages. properties file where I keep my bug messages

```
NotEmpty.registerDTO.username=This field is required.
Pattern.registerDTO.username=Please enter at least 6 characters(max. 36 characters). Only letters, numbers and special characters '_' and '-'.
```

However, the result of this operation appears to be 
https://zapodaj.net/d1a4f695e6a7d.png.html

Does not retrieve a local message from the. properties file.

How to set up for local messages to be downloaded from the properties file?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to configure the custom validation messages for Hibernate. The first bean configures the location of the validation messages to the custom `validationMessages` file (use any name). In the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` you can `@Override` the `getValidator()` method which returns the custom Validator.

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource rrbms = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    rrbms.setBasename("classpath:validationMessages");
    rrbms.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return rrbms;
}

@Bean(name = "validator")
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean lvfb = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    lvfb.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return lvfb;
}

@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    return validator();
}
```

Since you are okay with the default name `validationMessages.properties` or in case you use `WebConfigurationSupport`, the minimal setup is:

```
@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return validator;
}
```

Anyway, then you have **to refer** to the right property using the `message`.

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{6,36}", message="{Pattern.registerDTO.username}")
```

A good practice is not to name the property according to a field it is validating, but according to the type of the validation.

```
validation.notEmpty=This field is required.
validation.pattern.username=Please enter at least 6 characters(max. 36 characters). Only letters, numbers and special characters '_' and '-'.
validation.pattern.email=...
validation.pattern.phone=...
validation.size=...
```

Comment: Please enter at least 6 characters(max. 36 characters). I want to get 6 or 36 from another property / variable and I don't want to hardcode it like this in the message how would I go about doing that ?

Comment: @Denson: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36148965/3764965 You can combine properties.