# Spring test property override replaces whole array element

Tags: spring, configurationproperties

I am using `@ConfigurationProperties`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
@Component
public class MyProperties {
    private Nested single;
    private List<Nested> many;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Nested {
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}
```

test.properties

```
my.single.foo=A
my.single.bar=B
my.many[0].foo=C
my.many[0].bar=D
```

I am running test with the following configuration:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties",
    properties = {
            "my.single.bar=bb",
            "my.many[0].bar=dd"
    })
```

**The problem is that I get `my.many[0].foo=null` because as I understood Spring completely replaces first element in list with `{foo: null, bar: "dd"}`**

Please help.

Comment: actually everyone is struggling with "arrays in properties file", because there's no word about "arrays" in `java.util.Properties`  ...but spring seems to have work around. But still, I would not regard it as "defect", since `properties` is documented to have the highest precedence, and(they could argument) you (sort of) set `my.many[0].*=null` ... the fix is straightforward: provide `my.many[0].foo`, but of course nasty if you have "rich" properties ...is XML or YAML a feasible approach/try-out for you?

Comment: @xerx593 Are you saying this will work if I change my properties file to YAML?

Comment: no, i don't say "will" ...i'd say "it is worth trying" ...and i (still) would prefer xml to yaml. but if the "defect" still exists with xml or yaml, then it is clearly a defect (,  because these allow finer grained data structures...)

Comment: @xerx593 Ij ust tried with YAML. Doesn't work either. I also noticed that not only single element in array is erased, but all array elements are removed.

Answer (score 1):

I fought with this a lot, and found a reasonable workaround, so I thought I'd share it here.

Using Spring's capability of combining properties, as described here:
[Spring properties that depend on other properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136874/spring-properties-that-depend-on-other-properties), I've done this:

Original application.properties:

```
my.list[0].x = x0
my.list[0].y = y0
my.list[1].x = x1
my.list[1].y = y1
```

application.properties that allows overriding x0 externally:

```
overridable.property = x0
my.list[0].x = {overridable.property}
my.list[0].y = y0
my.list[1].x = x1
my.list[1].y = y1
```

and now `-Doverridable.property=xxx` replaces just what I need