# Is it possible to reuse one i18n property in another in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, thymeleaf

My i18n messages.properties

```
# e.g property
forgot.password = Forgot Password?

# Trying to reuse the above property
user.exists = User already exists. <a href="/forgot">#{forgot.password}</a>

# Work around
user.exists2 = User already exists. <a href="/forgot">{0}</a>
```

And inside my thymeleaf template

```
user.exists = [[#{user.exists}]]  
user.exists2 = [[#{user.exists2(#{forgot.password})}]]
```

output: 
user.exists = <a href="/forgot">#{forgot.password}</a>
user.exists2 = <a href="/forgot">Forgot Password?</a>

Comment: Remove the `#` in your properties file.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, but that did not work. It prints {forgot.password}. Also tried various combinations: ${forgot.password}, escaping with backslashes, etc.

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties